# $x,y,z \geqslant 0$, $x+y^2+z^3=1$, prove $x^2y+y^2z+z^2x < \frac12$

Tags: inequality

> $x,y,z \geqslant 0$, $x+y^2+z^3=1$, prove 
>   $$x^2y+y^2z+z^2x < \frac12$$

This inequality has been verified by Mathematica. $\frac12$ is not the best bound. I try to do AM-GM for this one but not yet success. The condition $x+y^2+z^3$ is very weird.

Comment: When $x=0.534,y=0.5$ and $z=0.6$ (exact decimal values) one has
$x^2y+y^2z+z^2x=0.484818$, so 0.5 is close to the best constant.

Comment: Mathematica gives the maximum value of $x^2y+y^2z+z^2x < \frac12$ as constrained to be $0.48562209920309984177$ for $x=0.55811253$, $y=0.49841201$, $z=0.57837131$.

Comment: I think, [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2202119/how-prove-this-inequality-abcde3-geq92abcabdabeacdade2bcdbcebde/2220653#2220653) method will be interesting too.

Comment: A nice solution is also given by anhduy98@AoPS here: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1238490

Answer (score 18):

The standard way of solving the problem on a conditional extremum is the method of Lagrange multipliers, which reduces it to a system of equations.

The greatest value of function 
$$f(x,y,z,\lambda) = x^2y+y^2z+z^2x+\lambda(x+y^2+z^3-1)$$
on the interval
$$x,y,z\in[0,1]$$
is reached or at its edges, or in the inner stationary point.

$\color{brown}{\textbf{Inner stationary points.}}$

The inner stationary points has zero partial derivatives 
$$\begin{cases}
f'_\lambda = x + y^2 + z^3 - 1 = 0\\
f'_x = z^2 + 2xy + \lambda = 0\\
f'_y = x^2 + 2yz + 2\lambda y = 0\\
f'_z = y^2 + 2zx + 3\lambda z^2 = 0.
\end{cases}$$
After the excluding of parameter $\lambda$ get the system
$$\begin{cases}
x + y^2 + z^3 - 1 = 0\\
x^2 + 2yz = 2y(z^2 + 2xy)\\
y^2 + 2zx = 3z^2(z^2 + 2xy),
\end{cases}$$
or
$$\begin{cases}
x + y^2 + z^3 - 1 = 0\\
(1-3y^2-z^3)^2-4y^4+2yz(1-z)=0\\
2z(1-3yz)(1-y^2-z^3)+y^2-3z^4=0.
\end{cases}$$

Using of [Groebner basis](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GroebnerBasis.html) allows to get [the positive solutions](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Groebner%20%7B%281-3y%5E2-z%5E3%29%5E2-4y%5E4%2B2yz%281-z%29%2C2z%281-3yz%29%281-y%5E2-z%5E3%29%2By%5E2-3z%5E4%7D%3D%7B0%2C0%7D)
$$
\genfrac{[}{.}{0}{0}{x\approx 0.16367,\quad y\approx 0.761982,\quad z\approx 0.634724,\quad f\approx 0.454882}
{x\approx 0.558113,\quad y\approx 0.498412,\quad z\approx 0.578371,\quad f\approx 0.485622}.
$$
Alternative way is shown below.

$\color{brown}{\textbf{The edges.}}$

The edges of the field are achieved when $x = 0$, $y = 0$ or $z = 0$.

Substitution $x = 0$ in the expressions for the partial derivatives leads to the system
$$
\begin{cases}
x=0\\
y^2+z^3 = 1\\
2yz+2\lambda y = 0\\
y^2+3\lambda z^2 = 0
\end{cases}
$$
with solutions
$$
\genfrac{[}{.}{0}{}
{x=0,\quad y=\sqrt{0.75},\quad z=\sqrt[3]{0.25}\approx 0.629991,\quad f\approx 0.47247}
{x=0,\quad y=0,\quad z=1,\quad f=0}$$

Substitution $y = 0$ in the expressions for the partial derivative leads to the system
$$
\begin{cases}
y=0\\
x+z^3=1\\
z^2+\lambda = 0\\
2zx+3\lambda z^2 = 0
\end{cases}
$$
with solution
$$x=0.6,\quad y=0,\quad z=\sqrt[3]{0.4}\approx 0.736806,\quad f\approx 0.32573.$$

Substitution $z = 0$ in the expressions for the partial derivative leads to the system
$$
\begin{cases}
z=0\\
x+y^2=1\\
2xy+\lambda = 0\\
x^2+2\lambda y = 0
\end{cases}
$$
with solutions
$$
\genfrac{[}{.}{0}{}
{x=0.8,\quad y=\sqrt{0.2}\approx 0.447214,\quad z=0,\quad f\approx 0.286217}
{x=0,\quad y=0,\quad z=1,\quad f=0}
$$

The values of function at the vertices of the area (unit parallelepiped) equal to zero.

So the greatest value approximately equals to $0.485622$. Given accuracy of calculations provides the inequality
$$\boxed{x^2y+y^2z+z^2x<1/2.}$$

$\color{brown}{\textbf{System resolving, alternative way.}}$

Set condition allows us to reduce the problem to finding unconditional extremes of
$$f(y,z)=(1-y^2-z^3)^2y+y^2z+z^2(1-y^2-z^3).$$
Necessary optimality conditions in the field have the form:
$$\begin{cases}
f'_y = (1-y^2-z^3)^2-4y^2(1-y^2-z^3)+2yz-2yz^2 = 0\\
f'_z = -6yz^2(1-y^2-z^3)+y^2+2z(1-y^2-z^3)-3z^4 = 0,
\end{cases}$$
or
$$\begin{cases}
5y^4+y^2(6z^3-6)+y(2z-2z^2)+(z^3-1)^2 = 0\\
6y^3z^2+y^2(1-2z)+6y(z^3-1)z^2-5z^4+2z = 0.
\end{cases}$$

If to consider the coefficient of the highest power of $y$ as denominator in equation, and the remaining coefficients - numerators, we get the above equations. Then we can subtract the second equation factor $y$ from the first and repeat subtraction with factor $1$, obtaining the system

$$\begin{cases}
C_{2,2}(z)y^2 + C_{2,1}(z)y + C_{2,0}(z) = 0\\
6y^3z^2+y^2(1-2z)+6y(z^3-1)z^2-5z^4+2z = 0,
\end{cases}$$
where 
$$C_{2,2}(z) = 36z^7-36z^4+20z^2-20z+5,$$
$$C_{2,1}(z) = 18z^6+102z^5-30z^2,$$
$$C_{2,0}(z) = 36z^{10}-72z^7+50z^5+11z^4-20z^2+10z.$$

Thus, the order of the first equation in $y$ reduced from fourth to second.
Likewise, lowering the order of the second equation by a first equation, we obtain

$$\begin{cases}
C_{2,2}(z)y^2 + C_{2,1}(z)y + C_{2,0}(z) = 0\\
D_{2,2}(z)y^2 + D_{2,1}(z)y + D_{2,0}(z) = 0,\\
\end{cases}\qquad(1)$$
where
$$D_{2,2}(z) = 180z^8+576z^7-72z^5-144z^4+40z^3-60z^2+30z-5,$$
$$D_{2,1}(z) = 180z^7-30z^6-30z^5-60z^3+30z^2,$$
$$D_{2,0}(z) = 180z^{11}-252z^8+100z^6-28z^5+25z^4-40z^3+40z^2-10z.$$

The system $(1)$ is a linear in the unknowns $y^2$ and $y$, so
$$y^2=\dfrac{\Delta_2(z)}{\Delta_0(z)},\quad y=\dfrac{\Delta_1(z)}{\Delta_0(z)},\qquad(2)$$
where
$$\Delta_0(z) = C_{2,2}(z)D_{2,1}(z) - C_{2,1}(z)D_{2,2}(z),$$
$$\Delta_2(z) = -C_{2,0}(z)D_{2,1}(z) + C_{2,1}(z)D_{2,0}(z),$$
$$\Delta_1(z) = -C_{2,2}(z)D_{2,0}(z) + C_{2,0}(z)D_{2,2}(z),$$
or
$$\Delta_0(z) = 90z^{10}-828z^9-1662z^8-144z^7+396z^6+1028z^5-200z^4+180z^3-220z^2+10z,$$
$$\Delta_2(z) = -90z^{13}+540z^{12}+30z^{11}+234z^{10}-864z^9-290z^8+256z^7+74z^6+220z^5-160z^4+100z^3-50z^2,$$
$$\Delta_1(z) = 576z^{13}-1296z^{10}+90z^9+815z^8+444z^7-5z^6-580z^5+126z^4+10z^3+80z^2-30z-5.$$

From $(2)$ for $\Delta_0(z)\not=0$ should be
$$\Delta_1^2(z) - \Delta_2(z)\Delta_0(z) = 0,$$
or 
$$331776z^{26}-1484892z^{23}-19440z^{22}+1233720z^{21}+3079404z^{20}+195732z^{19}-3189924z^{18}-3109428z^{17}+368233z^{16}+2734116z^{15}+1243978z^{14}-741000z^{13}-805907z^{12}+75696z^{11}+164040z^{10}+82560z^9-172194z^8+53440z^7-10290z^6+32440z^5-7460z^4-4400z^3+100z^2+300z+25 = 0.$$

The coefficients are particially calculated using the Mathcad package, and $\mathcal{polyroots}()$ function is also used, which calculates all the roots of the polynomial by the "accompanying matrix" method.

Calculating values $y$ with $(2)$ and $x,f$ by the formula
$$x = 1-y^2-z^3,\quad f=xy^2+yz^2+zx^2$$
and checking them by substituting in the original system, we obtain the following stationary points with the positive coordinates:
$$
(x,y,z,f)\in\left[\genfrac{}{}{0pt}{0}
  {(0.5581125,\ 0.4984120,\ 0.5783713,\ 0.4856221)}
  {(0.1636702,\ 0.7619816,\ 0.6347238,\ 0.4548812)}
\right.
$$

Comment: Less time consuming way to set out as a separate answer.

Comment: The problem with this is that the equations were solved using some solver (approximations) and so cant represent exact solution

Comment: Worst there is no proof that the approximate solutions give global maximum.

Comment: @stalker2133 Approximation seems a single way to get exact maximum, because we've got a hard task. "Classic" (clear) proof is shown there in another my answer, it was in my link. But never note it.)))

Comment: I checked the link but I wonder why we are using determinant to tell about solutions of non- linear equations.

Comment: @stalker2133 I've deleted the second post and added new way in the main one.

Comment: Ok.  I will have a look at it again.

Comment: @Wiley simplified decision

Answer (score 4):

**Update**: A simpler prof (2023/03/24)

Since $y^2 + \frac{1}{4} \ge y$, it suffices to prove that
$$x^2(y^2 + \tfrac{1}{4}) + y^2 z + z^2 x < \frac{1}{2}.$$
Since $y^2 = 1-x-z^3$, it suffices to prove that
$$4x^3+(4z^3-5)x^2+(-4z^2+4z)x+4z^4-4z+2 > 0. \tag{1}$$

We have
\begin{align*}
 &4x^3+(4z^3-5)x^2+(-4z^2+4z)x+4z^4-4z+2\\
 =\ & 4x\left(x + \frac{1}{2}z^3 - \frac{5}{8}\right)^2
 +  \left( 4\,z-4\,{z}^{2}-{z}^{6}+\frac52\,{z}^{3}-{\frac {25}{16}} \right) 
 x+4\,{z}^{4}-4\,z+2.
  \tag{2}
\end{align*}

It suffices to prove that
$$\left( 4\,z-4\,{z}^{2}-{z}^{6}+\frac52\,{z}^{3}-{\frac {25}{16}} \right) 
x+4\,{z}^{4}-4\,z+2 > 0.$$

Since $4z^4 - 4z + 2 = (2z^2 - 1)^2 + (2z - 1)^2 > 0$,
we only need to prove the case that
$4\,z-4\,{z}^{2}-{z}^{6}+\frac52\,{z}^{3}-{\frac {25}{16}} < 0$. Since $x + z^3 \le 1$, it suffices to prove that
$$\left( 4\,z-4\,{z}^{2}-{z}^{6}+\frac52\,{z}^{3}-{\frac {25}{16}} \right) 
(1 - z^3) + 4\,{z}^{4}-4\,z+2 > 0$$
or
$$16\,{z}^{9}-56\,{z}^{6}+64\,{z}^{5}+65\,{z}^{3}-64\,{z}^{2}+7 > 0.$$

We have
\begin{align*}
 &16\,{z}^{9}-56\,{z}^{6}+64\,{z}^{5}+65\,{z}^{3}-64\,{z}^{2}+7\\
 ={}& \frac{1}{16} ( 16{z}^{4}-1 ) ^{2}z+ \frac{7}{2}( 4{z}^{2}-1
 ) ^{2} ( 1-z ) z+ \frac58( 4{z}^{2}-1 ) ^
 {2}z + 7 ( 2z-1 ) ^{2} ( 1-z ) z\\[6pt]
 &\qquad + 42(z - 9/16)^2 z + \frac{87}{4} z^2 - \frac{3133}{128}z + 7\\
 >{}& 0
\end{align*}
where we use $\frac{87}{4} z^2 - \frac{3133}{128}z + 7 > 0$
for all $z \in [0, 1]$.

We are done.

Comment: $4z^4-4z+2=(2z^2-1)^2+(2z-1)^2$

Comment: @YuriNegometyanov  Very nice! Thanks.

Comment: And try $18\times(1) - (6x+2z^3-5/2)\times(1)',$ this is correct in the stationary point.

Comment: @YuriNegometyanov  Thanks. Which one is $(1)'$?

Comment: Partial derivative of LHS(1) by $x.$

Comment: @YuriNegometyanov Thanks. What do you mean by {try $18\times(1) - (6x+2z^3-5/2)\times(1)'$}? It is not non-negative.

Comment: It could help. But you're right.

Comment: I've used this technology in my new answer, after preparation.

Answer (score 3):

This answer is incomplete.

Let $A=x+y^2$, $B=y^2+z^3$ and $C=z^3+x$.

Claim: $x^2y \leq \dfrac{A}{2}x^{3/2}$, 
$y^2z \leq \dfrac{B^{2/3}}{4^{2/3}}y^{4/3}$, $z^2x \leq \dfrac{C^{4/3}}{4^{2/3}}x^{1/3}$.

Assuming the claim, we note that $A+B+C=2$ and we need to prove that the given sum is less than $\dfrac{A+B+C}{4}$.

Comment: Isn't a+b+c=2, and that would change the answer

Comment: Thanks, I'll modify the proof.

Comment: so assuming those three additional inequalities, can you at least prove the requested inequality? If not what progress does this represent?

Answer (score 3):

[image]

The method to be employed here is exactly the same as in a previous answer:

- [Olympiad inequality $\sum_{cyc} \frac{x^4}{8x^3+5y^3} \geqslant \frac{x+y+z}{13}$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1775572/olympiad-inequality-sum-cyc-fracx48x35y3-geqslant-fracxyz13/1787422#1787422)

Let $u = x$ , $v = y^2$ , $w = z^3$ , then $u,v,w \ge 0$ , $u+v+w=1$ and the inequality to be established:
$$
x^2y+y^2z+z^2x < \frac12 \quad \Longrightarrow \quad f(u,v,w) = u^2v^{1/2}+v\,w^{1/3}+w^{2/3}u < \frac12
$$
The maximum of this function inside the equilateral triangle must shown to be less than $1/2$.
There is no symmetry argument, because the latter is effectively destroyed by the "weird" condition $x+y^2+z^3=1$ , as it is called.
Another [proof without words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_without_words) is attempted
by plotting a contour map of the function, as depicted. Levels (`nivo`) of these isolines are defined (in Delphi Pascal) as:

```
nivo := min + sqrt(g/grens)*(max-min); { sqrt = square root ; grens = 25 ; g = 0..grens }
```

The darkness of the isolines is proportional to the (positive) function values; they are almost black near the maximum and almost white near the minimum values.
Maximum and minimum values of the function are observed to be:

```
 4.58251457205350E-0003 < f < 4.85621276951755E-0001 < 1/2
```

The little $\color{blue}{\mbox{blue}}$ spot is where $\left|f(u,v,w) - \mbox{max}\right|< 0.0002$ .
This maximum is close to values found by other people here, but not quite.
Perhaps it's interesting to know the position of the maximum as well:

```
(x,y,z) = ( 5.58304528246164E-0001 , 4.97693736095187E-0001 , 5.78892473099889E-0001 )
```

I have no idea how to convert these numerical values into something more analytical.

EDIT. What you see is what you get :-) Without doubt. Some decent error analysis reveals that the value of the maximum to be trusted *in this answer* is : $\;0.48562 \pm 0.00003\;$ , quite in agreement with values given elsewhere (e.g. in the comment by Steve Kass).

Answer (score 2):

I don't think the best bound can be solved for analytically.

using Lagrange multipliers , I tried to maximize $x^2y+y^2z+z^2x$ $\quad$ subject to the constraint $x+y^2+z^3=1$

maximize $g=x^2y+y^2z+z^2x+\lambda(x+y^2+z^3-1)$

$\frac {\partial g}{\partial x}=0:2xy+z^2+\lambda=0$

$\frac {\partial g}{\partial y}=0:x^2+2yz+2\lambda y=0$

$\frac {\partial g}{\partial z}=0:y^2+2zx+3\lambda z^2=0$

$\frac {\partial g}{\partial \lambda}=0:x+y^2+z^3-1=0$

$x\frac {\partial g}{\partial x}=0:2x^2y+z^2x+\lambda x=0$

$y\frac {\partial g}{\partial y}=0:x^2y+2y^2z+2\lambda y^2=0$

$z\frac {\partial g}{\partial z}=0:y^2z+2z^2x+3\lambda z^3=0$

$3(x^2y+y^2z+z^2x)=-\lambda (x+2y^2+3z^3)=(2xy+z^2)(x+2y^2+3z^3)$

If the global maximum occur on $ x, y, z \ge 0 $ then we can solve $(2xy+z^2)(x+2y^2+3z^3) \ge 0 $ for $x, y, z \ge 0 $

If no local maximum occur at $ x, y,z \ge 0 $ then we have to search for farthest points from the point of global minimum.

Comment: It looks like all we have to do is search for the farthest point away from the local minimum that also satisfies the constraint.

Answer (score 2):

Let $x=0$.

Then $y^2+z^3=1 \Rightarrow z^3=1-y^2$

Seek to maximise $p=y^2z=y^2(1-y^2)^{\frac 13}$

WLOG let $u=y^2$ so that $p=u(1-u)^{\frac 13}$

$\frac {dp}{du}=(1-u)^{\frac 13}-u{\frac 13}(1-u)^{-\frac 23}$

$\frac {dp}{du}=\frac 13(3-4u)(1-u)^{-\frac 23}$

Maximum is at $u=\frac 34$

Thus maximum is $p=\frac 34(\frac 14)^{\frac 13}$

$p \le \frac 34(\frac 14)^{\frac 13}$

$p^3 \le \frac {27}{64}\frac 14$

$p^3 \le \frac {27}{256} < \frac {32}{256}$

$p^3 < \frac {1}{8}$

$p < \frac {1}{2}$

We then have to demonstrate that any increase in $x$ creates corresponding decreases in $y^2$ and $z^2$ such that the other two terms in the expression $x^2y+y^2z+z^2x$ increase more slowly than the decrease in $p$.

Comment: You find a maximum at $p = \frac{3}{4}\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}} \approx 0.47247$. However, in the comments to the question, Ewan Delanoy found a point which has value $0.484818$. So I don't think your last paragraph will work?

Comment: I was hoping someone else would address that...

Comment: It also seems odd that the maximum I found is at $\frac {\sqrt 3} 2$. Is there some trig transformation that would make this easier?

Comment: @stalker2133 look there: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1775498/x-y-z-geqslant-0-xy2z3-1-prove-x2yy2zz2x-frac12/1801749#1801749

Comment: @stalker2133 There are two my answers. Follow link, please.

Comment: @stalker2133: Welcome in 2016! Computers exist for more than half a century now. Instead of "thinking hard" and accomplishing essentially nothing, wouldn't it be wise to simply use these machines for the purpose
of exploring computationally feasible problems, like this sort of inequalities? Everybody who is employing mathematics in practice is
doing this on a routinely base, except mathematicians themselves. Why?

Answer (score 1):

$\color{green}{\textbf{Computer free version of 17.12.20.}}$

$\color{brown}{\textbf{Preliminary notes.}}$

We should prove the inequality$\;f(x,y,z)= x^2y+y^2z+z^2x \le \frac12\;$ under the conditions
$x+y^2+z^3=1,\;$ $x,y,z\in [0,1].$

In accordance with the @RiverLi answer,

---

- $y\le y^2+\frac14,\tag1$
- $2-4(x^2y+y^2z+z^2x)\ge 2-x^2-(4x^2+4z)(1-x-z^3)-4z^2x,\tag2$

---

where $(1)$ follows from the evident $\;\left(y-\frac12\right)^2 \ge0\;$.

At the same time, for $\;t\in[0,1]\;$
$$t^4-t+\frac3{4\sqrt[\large3]4} = \left(t^2-\sqrt[\large3]2t-\frac1{2\sqrt[\large3]2}\right)\left(t^2 +\sqrt[\large3]2 t +\frac3{2\sqrt[\large3]2}\right) $$
$$= \left(t-\frac1{\sqrt[\large3]4}\right)^2\left(t^2+\sqrt[\large3]2 t 
+\frac3{2\sqrt[\large3]2}\right) \ge 0,$$

$$t\le t^4+H,\quad \text{where}\quad H=\frac3{4\sqrt[\large3]4} = \dfrac12\sqrt[\large3]{\dfrac{27}{32}}<\dfrac12,\quad H\approx0.47247.\tag3$$

$\color{brown}{\textbf{The edges of area.}}$

Taking in account $(1)$ and $(3),$ one can get
\begin{align}
&f(x,y,0) = x^2y \le (1-y^2)^2y\,\bigg|_{\large y=\frac1{\sqrt5}} = \dfrac{16}{25\sqrt5}<0.28622,  \\[4pt]
&f(x,0,z) = z^2x = (1-z^3)z^2 \le (1-z^3)z \le H, \\[4pt]
&f(0,y,z) = y^2z = (1-z^3)z \le H.
\end{align}

Thus, the given inequality is correct on the edges of the area.

$\color{brown}{\textbf{The inner stationary points.}}$

Taking in account $(2)$ and $(1)$ in the form of
$\;4z\le 4z^2+1,\;$
it suffices to prove the inequality $\;g(x,z)\ge0,\;$ where
$$g(x,z) = 2-x^2-(4x^2+1+4z^2)(1-x-z^3)-4z^2x,$$
$$g(x,z) = 1+4x^2z^3 + (4z^5+z^3-4z^2) + (4x^3-5x^2+x),\tag4$$
under the conditions $\;\;x,z\in(0,1).$

Stationary points should satisfy the system $\;g'_x = g'_z =0,\;$
or
\begin{cases}
g'_x = 8z^3x + 12 x^2 - 10x + 1 = 0\\[4pt]
g'_z = 12x^2z^2+20 z^4+3z^2-8z = 0,\tag5
\end{cases}

and then
\begin{cases}
12x^2z = 8-3z-20z^3\hspace{163mu} \left[z^{-1}\times(5.2)\right]\\
8z^4x +(8-3z-20z^3) - 10xz + z = 0,\qquad \left[z\times(5.1)\right]\\
\end{cases}
$$x = h_1(z) = \dfrac{4-z-10z^3}{5z-4z^4},\quad x^2 = h_2(z) = \dfrac{8-3z-20z^3}{12z}\tag6.$$

At the same time, from $(4),(5)$ should
\begin{align}
&5g(x,z) = 5g - xg'_x - z g'_z\\[4pt]
& = 5+20x^2z^3 + (20z^5+5z^3-20z^2) + (20x^3-25x^2+5x)\\[4pt]
& - x(8z^3x + 12 x^2 - 10x + 1) - z(12x^2z^2+20 z^4+3z^2-8z)\\[4pt]
& = 5 + 4 x + 8x^3 -15x^2 - 12 z^2 + 2 z^3,
\end{align}
$$5g(x,z) = 5 - 15h_2(z) + 4 h_1(z) (1+2h_2(z)) - 12 z^2 + 2 z^3.\tag7$$
Substitution of $(6)$ to $(7)$ represents the inequality $\;g(x,z) \ge 0\;$ in the form of
$$256 - 568 z + 501 z^2 - 1280 z^3 + 1180 z^4 - 300 z^5 + 1600 z^6 - 624 z^7 - 96 z^8\ge 0.\tag8$$

Since
$$h(z)-1=\dfrac{4z^4-10z^3-6z+4}{5z-4z^4}=\dfrac{2(1-2z)(2+z+2z^2-z^3)}{5z-4z^4},$$
then $\;h(z)>1,\;$ if $\;z\in\left(0,\frac12\right).\;$

Besides, $\;h(z)\;$ has a positive denominator and  decreasing numerator in the interval $\;z\in(0,1],\;$ wherein $\;h\left(\frac7{10}\right) = -\frac{325}{6349}<0.\;$
Therefore, $\;h(z)< 0,\;$ if $\;z\in\left[\frac7{10},1\right].\;$

Thus, all inner stationary points belong to the interval $\;z\in\left[\dfrac12,\dfrac7{10}\right).\;$

And now, substitution $\;z=\dfrac{6+t}{10},\;t\in[-1,1),\;$ transforms $(8)$ to the evident inequality
$$-3 t^8 - 339 t^7 - 6214 t^6 - 13083 t^5 + 1041140 t^4\\ + 12923432 t^3 + 64494426 t^2 - 898904 t + 13278632 \ge 0.$$

**Done!**

Comment: 1) Should it be $f(x,0,z) = z^2x = (1-z^3)z^2 \le (1-z^3)z \le H, 
f(0,y,z) = y^2z = (1-z^3)z \le H$?

Comment: 2) How do you get the 3rd equation in (5)? How do you get the equation between (5) and (6)? More details should be given.

Comment: 3) Also, the 1st equation in (4) is different from RHS of (2)?

Comment: @RiverLi Thanks! Fixed and detalized.

Comment: 4) Check (6) $x = \cdots$

Comment: @RiverLi The bug fixed, thank you!

Comment: The sentence around "has a vertical asymptote at", maybe the details should be given how to get $h(z) > 1$? Also, the next paragraph...

Comment: I think that it is basically fine. (+1)   I think that the part after "In the stationary points the partial derivatives" is not addressed nicely. By the way, the last inequality should be written in exact form (rational numbers or integers).

Answer (score 0):

More idea than answer, but it might be of help.

If we replace $x$ by $x^2$ and $z$ by $z^{2/3}$, the constraint becomes $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$ and the inequality becomes

$$x^4y+y^2z^{2/3}+z^{4/3}x^2\lt{1\over2}$$

This looks worse, but the advantage of constraining $(x,y,z)$ to the unit sphere is that we can switch over to spherical coordinates, writing $x=\sin\theta\cos\phi$, $y=\sin\theta\sin\phi$, and $z=\cos\theta$, and make use of some trig identities.  Ultimately, with a final change of variable $u=(\cos\theta)^{2/3}$ and $v=-\cos2\phi$, the inequality to prove (if I've done the algebra correctly) is

$$(1-u^2)^{5/2}\left({(1-v)(1+v)^4\over8}\right)^{1/2}+(u-u^4)(1+v)+(u^2-u^5)(1-v)\lt1\quad\text{for }0\le u,v\le1$$

This "reduces" the problem to the unpleasant chore of finding (or bounding) a  function of two variables over the unit square.  I'll end by noting that if we focus on the easy portion of the function, $f(u,v)=(u-u^4)(1+v)+(u^2-u^5)(1-v)$, we find that $f$ is maximized when $v=1$ and $u=1/\sqrt[3]4$, and

$$f\left({1\over\sqrt[3]4},1\right)={3\over2\sqrt[3]4}\approx0.94494$$

so the true minimum of the full function is not much less than $1$. (Just a note: I multiplied both sides of the original inequality by $2$ to clear out some denominators.  Dividing by $2$ changes $0.94494$ to $0.47247$, which is, as it should be, less than the numerical result $0.48562209920309984177$ reported by Steve Kass in comments below the OP.)