# Prove $\left(\frac{a+1}{a+b} \right)^{\frac25}+\left(\frac{b+1}{b+c} \right)^{\frac25}+\left(\frac{c+1}{c+a} \right)^{\frac25} \geqslant 3$

Tags: inequality, contest-math

$a,b,c >0$ and $a+b+c=3$, prove
$$\left(\frac{a+1}{a+b} \right)^{\frac25}+\left(\frac{b+1}{b+c} \right)^{\frac25}+\left(\frac{c+1}{c+a} \right)^{\frac25} \geqslant 3$$

I try to apply AM-GM
$$\left(\frac{a+1}{a+b} \right)^{\frac25}+\left(\frac{b+1}{b+c} \right)^{\frac25}+\left(\frac{c+1}{c+a} \right)^{\frac25} \geqslant 3\cdot \sqrt[3]{\left(\frac{a+1}{a+b} \right)^{\frac25}\left(\frac{b+1}{b+c} \right)^{\frac25}\left(\frac{c+1}{c+a} \right)^{\frac25}}$$
Thus it remains to prove
$$\left(\frac{a+1}{a+b} \right)\left(\frac{b+1}{b+c}\right)\left(\frac{c+1}{c+a} \right) \geqslant 1   $$ with the condition $a+b+c=3.$
 But I found the counter example for $$\left(\frac{a+1}{a+b} \right)\left(\frac{b+1}{b+c}\right)\left(\frac{c+1}{c+a} \right) \geqslant 1   $$ :(

Comment: a=1 b=1 c=1 equations is true

Comment: What was your counter example? Also, maybe $a+b=3-c$ will help.

Comment: $a=1.1, b=1.1,c =0.8$

Comment: Hard to tell from the first look, but I think the problem is that you do not use the fact that the exponent is $\frac{2}{5}$ in your proof. So, using your method we can 'prove' the first inequality for any exponent, which can't be true

Comment: actually all a=b=k>1 violate this inequality. the last inequality is incorrect. the jump from AM , GM inequality to last inequality is incorrect.

Comment: New "Olympiad" edition.

Comment: @HN_NH   The Buffalo Way (BW) works. But I am afraid it is not what you want.

Comment: @HN_NH, I need to the help_ https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4031429/822157, thanks a real lot !

Answer (score 0):

$\color{green}{\textbf{The bounds.}}$

For $c=0,\ b=3-a$ and WLOG $0<a\le\frac32,$ we have the inequality
$$F(a) = \left(\frac{a+1}3\right)^{2/5} + \left(\frac{4-a}{3-a}\right)^{2/5} +\left(\frac{1}{a}\right)^{2/5}\geq3,$$
$$F'(a)=\frac25\left(\frac13\left(\frac{a+1}3\right)^{-3/5} + \frac1{(3-a)^2}\left(\frac{4-a}{3-a}\right)^{-3/5} - \left(\frac{1}{a}\right)^{7/5}\right),$$
with the [root](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2F3((a%2B1)%2F3)%5E(-3%2F5)%2B1%2F(3-a)%5E2((4-a)%2F(3-a))%5E(-3%2F5)-(1%2Fa)%5E(7%2F5)%3D0) at $a_m\approx1.34387,$ so minimum of LHS achieves at $a=a_m$ and equals to
$$3.00248>3,$$
then the inequality is satisfied.

The same result can be obtained, if to use the numerical inequalities

- $\frac{123}{136}>\left(\frac79\right)^{2/5}>\frac{104}{115},\; \frac{43}{57}>\left(\frac85\right)^{-3/5}>\frac{89}{118},\;\frac{123}{184}>\left(\frac34\right)^{7/5}>\frac{125}{187}.$

Then
$$\lim\limits_{a\to 0}=-\infty,\quad F'\left(1\right) = \dfrac2{15}\left(\sqrt[\Large5]{\dfrac{27}8}+\dfrac34\sqrt[\Large5]{\dfrac8{27}}-3\right)< 0,$$
$$F'\left(\dfrac32\right) = \dfrac2{15}\left(\sqrt[\Large5]{\dfrac{125}{216}}+\dfrac43\sqrt[\Large5]{\dfrac{125}{27}}-2\sqrt[\Large5]{\dfrac23}\right) ,$$
$$F'\left(\dfrac32\right) = \dfrac2{15}\sqrt[\Large5]{\dfrac23}\left(\sqrt[\Large5]{\dfrac{125}{144}}+\dfrac43\sqrt[\Large5]{\dfrac{125}{18}}-2\right) >0,$$
$$F'\left(\dfrac43\right) =\frac25\left(\frac37\left(\frac79\right)^{2/5} + \frac9{25}\left(\frac85\right)^{-3/5} - \left(\frac34\right)^{7/5}\right) $$
$$<\frac25\left(\frac37\frac{123}{136}+\frac9{25}\frac{43}{57}-\frac{125}{187}\right) = -\dfrac{2711}{731500} < 0,$$
$$F'\left(\dfrac43\right) > \frac25\left(\frac37\frac{104}{115} +\frac9{25}\frac{89}{118}-\frac{123}{184}\right) = -\dfrac{17811}{4749500},$$

and for $a\in\left(\dfrac43,\dfrac32\right)$
$$F(a) > F\left(\dfrac43\right) + F'\left(\dfrac43\right)\left(a-\dfrac43\right)$$
$$=\left(\frac79\right)^{2/5} + \frac85\left(\frac85\right)^{-3/5} + \dfrac43\left(\frac34\right)^{7/5} + \dfrac16 F'\left(\dfrac43\right) \left(a-\dfrac43\right)$$
$$>\frac{104}{115}\left(1+\dfrac{6}{35}\left(a-\dfrac43\right)\right) 
+\frac{356}{295}\left(1+\dfrac9{100}\left(a-\dfrac43\right)\right) 
+\frac{500}{561} -\dfrac{123}{460}\left(a-\dfrac43\right),$$

[image: Approximation of F(a)]
$$F(a) > F\left(\dfrac43\right) + \dfrac16 F'\left(\dfrac43\right) $$ $$>\frac{104}{115}\,\frac{36}{35}+\frac{356}{295}\,\frac{203}{200}+\frac{500}{561} - \frac{41}{920} > 3.001768 >3.$$

$\color{green}{\textbf{Inequality transformation.}}$

Using the condition, one can write the original inequality in the form
$$\left(\frac{a+1}{3-c}\right)^{\frac25}+\left(\frac{b+1}{3-a} \right)^{\frac25}+\left(\frac{c+1}{3-b}\right)^{\frac25}.\qquad(1)$$
Let
$$x=\dfrac{3-a}{3-c},\quad y=\dfrac{3-b}{3-c},\qquad(2)$$
then
$$\frac{-x+2y+2}3 = \frac{a+1}{3-c},\quad \frac{2x-y+2}{3x} = \frac{b+1}{3-a},\quad \frac{2x+2y-1}{3y}= \frac{c+1}{3-b}.\qquad(3)$$
For example,
$$\dfrac{-x+2y+2}{3} = \dfrac{a-3+2(6-b-c)}{3(3-c)} = \dfrac{a-3+2(3+a)}{3(3-c)}=\dfrac{a+1}{3-c}.$$
This allows to prove the inequality
$$\left(\frac{-x+2y+2}3\right)^{2/5}+\left(\frac{2x-y+2}{3x} \right)^{2/5}+\left(\frac{2x+2y-1}{3y}\right)^{2/5}\geq3$$
for
$$x,y>0.$$

$\color{green}{\textbf{Primary optimization.}}$

To do this, it suffices to find the least value of the function
$$f(x,y)=\left(\frac{-x+2y+2}3\right)^{2/5}+\left(\frac{2x-y+2}{3x} \right)^{2/5}+\left(\frac{2x+2y-1}{3y}\right)^{2/5}$$
for positive $x,y.$

The stationary points of the function can be found by equating to zero the partial derivatives $f_x$ and $f_y$, and that gives
$$\begin{cases}
-\dfrac25\left(\dfrac{-x+2y+2}1\right)^{-3/5}+\dfrac{2(y-2)}{5x^2}\left(\dfrac{2x-y+2}{x} \right)^{-3/5}+\dfrac4{5y}\left(\dfrac{2x+2y-1}{y}\right)^{-3/5}=0\\[4pt]
\dfrac45\left(\dfrac{-x+2y+2}1\right)^{-3/5}-\dfrac2{5x}\left(\dfrac{2x-y+2}{x} \right)^{-3/5}-\dfrac{2(2x-1)}{5y^2}\left(\dfrac{2x+2y-1}{y}\right)^{-3/5}=0,
\end{cases}$$
$$\begin{cases}
(y-2)x^{-7/5}(2x-y+2)^{-3/5}+2y^{-2/5}(2x+2y-1)^{-3/5}=(-x+2y+2)^{-3/5}\\[4pt]
x^{-2/5}(2x-y+2)^{-3/5}+(2x-1)y^{-7/5}(2x+2y-1)^{-3/5}=2(-x+2y+2)^{-3/5},
\end{cases}$$
$$
\begin{pmatrix}y-2&2y\\x&2x-1\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
x^{-7/5}\left(\dfrac{-x+2y+2}{2x-y+2}\right)^{3/5}\\
y^{-7/5}\left(\dfrac{-x+2y+2}{2x+2y-1}\right)^{3/5}
\end{pmatrix}
=\begin{pmatrix}1\\2\end{pmatrix}.
$$
[from whence](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7Bx%5E%7B-7%2F5%7D((-x%2B2y%2B2)%2F(2x-y%2B2))%5E%7B3%2F5%7D,%20y%5E%7B-7%2F5%7D((-x%2B2y%2B2)%2F(2x%2B2y-1))%5E%7B3%2F5%7D%7D%20%3D%20%7B%7By-2,2y%7D,%7Bx,2x-1%7D%7D%5E(-1)%20.%20%7B%7B1%7D,%7B2%7D%7D)
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
x^{-7/5}\left(\dfrac{-x+2y+2}{2x-y+2}\right)^{3/5}\\
y^{-7/5}\left(\dfrac{-x+2y+2}{2x+2y-1}\right)^{3/5}
\end{pmatrix}
=\begin{pmatrix}\dfrac{-2x+4y+1}{4x+y-2}\\ \dfrac{x-2y+4}{4x+y-2} \end{pmatrix}.
\qquad(4)$$
To use $(4),$ there is more convenient returning to the source unknowns set.

$\color{green}{\textbf{Returning to the source unknowns set.}}$

Using $(2),$ we can obtain
$$\frac{4x+y-2}3 = \frac{4(3-a)+3-b-2(3-c)}{3(3-c)} = \frac{9-4a-b+2c}{3(3-c)} = \frac{9-(a+b+c)+3c-3a}{3(3-c)} = \frac{c-a+2}{3-c},$$
$$\frac{x-2y+4}3 = \frac{(3-a)-2(3-b)+4(3-c)}{3(3-c)} = \frac{9-a+2b-4c}{3(3-c)} = \frac{9-(a+b+c)+3b-3c}{3(3-c)} = \frac{b-c+2}{3-c},$$
$$\frac{2x+2y-1}3 = \frac{2(3-a)+2(3-b)-(3-c)}{3(3-c)} = \frac{9-2a-2b+c}{3(3-c)} = \frac{9-(a+b+c)+3a-3b}{3(3-c)} = \frac{c-a+2}{3-c}.$$
Taking in account $(2)-(4),$ we can obtain
$$\begin{cases}
\left(\dfrac{a+1}{3-c}\right)^{3/5}(3-c)^2(c-a+2) = t\\[4pt]
\left(\dfrac{b+1}{3-a}\right)^{3/5}(3-a)^2(a-b+2) = t\\[4pt]
\left(\dfrac{c+1}{3-b}\right)^{3/5}(3-b)^2(b-c+2) = t,
\end{cases}$$
where $t$ is some constant.

The final optimization can use this as condition for stationary points.

$\color{green}{\textbf{Final optimization.}}$

For
$$\Phi(a,b,c)=\sum_\bigcirc\left(\frac{a+1}{3-c}\right)^{2/5}$$
$$t\Phi(a,b,c) = \sum_\bigcirc\,(a+1)(3-c)(c-a+2) = \sum_\bigcirc (a^2(c-b-4)+2ab+4a) + 18,$$
$$t\Phi'_a(a,b,c) = -2 a (b - c + 4) + b^2 + 2 (b + c) - c^2 + 4 = 0,$$
$$t\sum_\bigcirc \Phi'_a(a,b,c) = 12 - 4(a+b+c) = 0,$$
$$t\Phi'_a(a,b,c) = -2 a (b - c + 4) + (3-a)(b-c+2) + 4 = (a-1)(3c-3b-10)=0.$$
Since $3c<3b+10,$ then, taking in account the symmetry, the single stationary point within the area is $(1,1,1)$.

Thus,
$$\color{green}{\mathbf{\boxed{\left(\frac{a+1}{a+b} \right)^{\frac25}+\left(\frac{b+1}{b+c} \right)^{\frac25}+\left(\frac{c+1}{c+a} \right)^{\frac25}\geq3.}}}$$

Comment: You really like [this kind of inequalities](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1829915/prove-left-fraca1ab-righta-left-fracb1bc-rightb-left-frac) don't you :)

Comment: @iamvegan And [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1804897/prove-xyy2z2z3x3-frac92-for-xyz-2/1821463#1821463), and [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1775498/x-y-z-geqslant-0-xy2z3-1-prove-x2yy2zz2x-frac12/1801630#1801630)... The serious base of "near-olympiad" inequalities seems as challenge. ;)

Comment: but these problems are for high school students only. The use of Lagrange multiplier or derivative with root finder from computer, or numerical methods are cheap and defeat the purpose of the problem.

Comment: @HN_NH Sometimes using of Lagrange multipliers leads to "Olympiad" success

Comment: @YuriNegometyanov, this would sound harsh, but before you lecture other people about "success", maybe you should have checked your algebra 101 before posting these mechanical proofs, e.g., (1) when $c=0$, $$\frac{b+1}{b+c}=\frac{\mathbf{4}-a}{3-a}$$ (2) when $A+B+C=3$, $$\frac{2-A}{C}=\frac{2(A+B+C)-\mathbf{3}A}{3C}$$  To whoever up-voted, have you actually read the "proof"??

Comment: I think it's not answer.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg I've elaborated one thin place. And I hope thar downvoters will change their wrong conclusions.

Comment: @HN_NH Glad to see your activity. Waiting for comments.

Comment: @YuriNegometyanov, +1 ; does ``\sum\bigcirc`` mean $\sum\limits_{cyc},$ thank you so much.

Comment: @haidangel Yes. Thank you too.

Comment: @YuriNegometyanov, do you enjoy my problems over here_ https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4035405/822157 ; including bountied topics that told on the warning above the question, I need to the help, they are flopped.

Answer (score 0):

Only a partial answer.

Assuming $a\le b\le c$, then we have $0<a\le1$ and $1\le c<3$. Now we have two cases, $b\le1$ and $b>1$. The case $b\le1$ is easy to deal with.

---

Assuming $0<a\le b\le1\le c<3$, we have
\begin{align}
\left(\frac{a+1}{a+b} \right)\left(\frac{b+1}{b+c}\right)\left(\frac{c+1}{c+a} \right) \ge 1
&\iff (a+1)(b+1)(4-a-b)\ge(a+b)(3-a)(3-b)\\
&\iff {\left(2-a-b\right)} {\left(1-a\right)} {\left(1-b\right)}\ge0.
\end{align}

---

Now assuming $0<a\le1\le b \le c<3$. Below is not an answer but only an analysis.

We want to know why this case is difficult, and why $\frac25$ is important.

Using the series expansion of $\exp$, and let $A = \operatorname{diag}\left(\ln\left(\frac{a+1}{a+b} \right),\ln\left(\frac{b+1}{b+c}\right),\ln\left(\frac{c+1}{c+a} \right)\right)$, then we have
\begin{align}
LHS 
&= \sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac25\right)^n\frac{\operatorname{tr}A^n}{n!}\\
&= 3 + \frac25\operatorname{tr}A + \frac12\cdot \left(\frac25\right)^2\operatorname{tr}A^2+ \frac16\cdot \left(\frac25\right)^3\operatorname{tr}A^3 +R_3,
\end{align}
where
$R_3 = \sum_{n=4}^\infty\left(\frac25\right)^n\frac{\operatorname{tr}A^n}{n!} \ge 0$, since $e^x-(1+x+x^2/2+x^3/6)$ is positive for any $x\in\mathbb R$.

Then we can prove the inequality if we have
$$\frac25\operatorname{tr}A + \frac12\cdot \left(\frac25\right)^2\operatorname{tr}A^2+ \frac16\cdot \left(\frac25\right)^3\operatorname{tr}A^3\ge\!\!\!?\;0,$$
which can be simplified to
$$75\operatorname{tr}A + 15\operatorname{tr}A^2+ 2\operatorname{tr}A^3\ge\!\!\!?\;0.\tag{1}$$

Numerical results suggest that using the 3 first terms is enough to prove the inequality. Note that in the first case where $b\le1$, using the first term $\operatorname{tr}A$ is enough (and what we did in the first part is in fact proving $\operatorname{tr}A\ge0$), that's why that case is easy.

So,

- Why the case $b\ge1$ is difficult?

  Because we have 2 more terms, $\operatorname{tr}A^2$ and $\operatorname{tr}A^3$, to deal with.
- Why $\frac25$ is important?

  Because $\frac25$ gives the coefficients 75, 15, and 2, which makes $75\operatorname{tr}A + 15\operatorname{tr}A^2+ 2\operatorname{tr}A^3\ge0$.

Comment: Nice your try +1

Answer (score 0):

Let $\frac{a+1}{a+b}=x^5,$ $\frac{b+1}{b+c}=y^5$ and $\frac{c+1}{c+a}=z^5$.

Thus,$\frac{4a+b+c}{a+b}=3x^5,$ $\frac{4b+c+a}{b+c}=3y^5$ and $\frac{4c+a+b}{c+a}=3z^5$, which says that the system
$$\left\{\begin{array}{ccc}(3x^5-4)a+(3x^5-1)b-c=0\\-a+(3y^5-4)b+(3y^5-1)c=0\\(3z^5-1)a-b+(3z^5-4)c=0\end{array}\right.$$ has infinitely many solutions $(a,b,c)$, which says $\Delta=0$ or
$$\prod_{cyc}(3x^5-4)+\prod_{cyc}(3x^5-1)-1+\sum_{cyc}(3x^5-4)(3y^5-1)=0$$ or
$$3x^5y^5z^5+2\sum_{cyc}(x^5-x^5y^5)-3=0$$ and we need to prove that
$$x^2+y^2+z^2\geq3,$$ which is wrong at the general.

But as  River Li said, it's enough to prove the  last inequality for the condition and for $x^5y^5z^5\geq\frac{25}{27}.$

Firstly, we'll prove that $x^5y^5z^5\geq\frac{25}{27}.$

Indeed, we need to prove that $$\prod_{cyc}\frac{a+1}{a+b}\geq\frac{25}{27}$$ or
$$\prod_{cyc}\frac{4a+b+c}{a+b}\geq25$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}\left(a^3-a^2b-a^2c+\frac{7}{3}abc\right)\geq0,$$
which is true by Schur.

Now, let $f(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2+z^2-3+\lambda\left(3x^5y^5z^5+2\sum\limits_{cyc}(x^5-x^5y^5)-3\right).$

Thus, in the minimum point $(x,y,z)$ we obtain $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}=0.$$
Thus, $$2x+5\lambda x^4(3y^5z^5+2-2y^5-2z^5)=0$$ or
$$2x^2+5\lambda x^5(3y^5z^5+2-2y^5-2z^5)=0.$$
Now, let $x\neq y$ and $x\neq z$ and since $$2y^2+5\lambda y^5(3x^5z^5+2-2x^5-2z^5)=0,$$ we obtain:
$$2(x+y)+10\lambda(x^4+x^3y+x^2y^2+xy^3+y^4)(1-z^5)=0.$$
By the same way $$2(x+z)+10\lambda(x^4+x^3z+x^2z^2+xz^3+z^4)(1-y^5)=0,$$ which gives
$$\frac{(x^4+x^3y+x^2y^2+xy^3+y^4)(1-z^5)}{x+y}=\frac{(x^4+x^3z+x^2z^2+xz^3+z^4)(1-y^5)}{x+z}$$ or
$$(y-z)\sum_{sym}\left(x^5y^4+x^5y^3z+\frac{1}{2}x^5y^2z^2+x^4y^4z+2x^4y^3z^2+\frac{1}{3}x^2y^2z^2+x^3y+\frac{1}{2}x^2y^2+x^2yz\right)=0,$$ which gives $y=z$.

Id est, it's enough to prove that $x^2+y^2+z^2\geq3$ for equality case of two variables.

Now, for $z=y$ we obtain:
$$3x^5y^{10}-2\left(2x^5y^5+y^{10}\right)+2(x^5+2y^5)=3$$ or
$$x^5=\frac{2y^{10}-4y^5+3}{3y^{10}-4y^5+2},$$ which gives
$$\frac{2y^{10}-4y^5+3}{3y^{10}-4y^5+2}\cdot y^{10}>\frac{25}{27}$$ or
$$y>\sqrt[5]{\frac{3-\sqrt{13}+2\sqrt{3+\sqrt{13}}}{6}}=0.945539...$$ and it remains to prove
$$\sqrt[5]{\left(\frac{2y^{10}-4y^5+3}{3y^{10}-4y^5+2}\right)^2}+2y^2\geq3$$ and since the last inequality is true for any $y>0.9436$, we are done.

Answer (score -1):

Partial Hint :

With your work one can show that :

$$\left(\frac{a+1}{3-x-a+a} \right)\left(\frac{3-x-a+1}{3-x-a+x}\right)\left(\frac{x+1}{x+a} \right) \geqslant 1   $$

With $1\leq a\leq 2$ and $x\in[2-a,1]$

I cannot prove it but using Bernoulli's inequality we have :

$$ \left(\frac{a+1}{x+a} \right)^{\frac25}+\frac{1}{1+\frac{2}{5}\left(\frac{3-x-a+a}{3-x-a+1}-1\right)}+\left(\frac{x+1}{3-x-a+x} \right)^{\frac25}\geq 3$$

With $x\in[0,1]$ and $1\leq a\leq 1.5$

Comment: @RiverLi Any idea to finish it ? Can you correct if my reasoning is wrong ? Thanks a lot !!

Comment: You only give partial result with some additional assumption. By the way, you should write your proof clearly. For example, you wrote "I forgot to mention that to works that we need ...", this is bad, you should write it in the beginning.

Comment: @RiverLi I give up it's too hard ! Without BW I don't see any progress...

Comment: @RiverLi a last question have you a counter-example for the inequality $f(x)\geq 6-g(x)$ ?

Comment: Do you mean $f(x) = A^{2/5} + B^{2/5} + C^{2/5}$ and $g = \dfrac{1}{1 + \frac{2}{5}(\frac{1}{A}-1)} + \cdots$. Try $a = 1.1$ and $x=0$.

Comment: @RiverLi Thanks I have a new inequality that I think true (checked with a calculator) can you confirm and if it's true have an idea to prove it ? Thanks !!!!!!

Comment: You need to deal with the other two $(\cdot)^{2/5}$.

Comment: I think the inequality is true, +1