# A travelled inequality found by discriminant

Tags: real-analysis, irreducible-polynomials, constants, discriminant, buffalo-way

> Given three real numbers $x, y, z$ so that $1\leq x, y, z\leq 8.$ Prove that
> $$\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{x}{y}\geq\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{2x}{y+ z}$$

I found this inequality by discriminant, we realised the homogenous, the generality of this problem. We assume $y= 1$ that leads $x^{2}+ x^{3}- zx- zx^{4}- 3z^{2}x^{2}+ z^{2}x^{4}+ z^{3}+ z^{3}x^{3}+ z^{4}- z^{4}x\geq 0.$ By jp.Wolfram|Alpha_ https://ja.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=discriminant%5Bx%5E2%2Bx%5E3-zx-zx%5E4-3z%5E2x%5E2%2Bz%5E2x%5E4%2Bz%5E3%2Bz%5E3x%5E3%2Bz%5E4-z%5E4x%2Cx%5D%3C%3D0 _of course $constant= 8$ is not the best here I think the one way that we can deal it is using substitution in $x, y, z$ but inhomogenous. I need to the help, thanks a *real* lot

Comment: What are we summing over exactly in $\sum \frac{x}{y}$?

Comment: @haidangel why you made the link large you can do ``` [ text ](link)``` also

Comment: @haidangel Yes, we can use substitutions. Did you do it?

Comment: @RiverLi does writing it of the for $$M{(a-b)}^2+N(c-a)(c-b)$$ help?I havent tried it

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore I think about $y=\min(x,y,z)=1$, $x = 1 + \frac{7}{1+s}$ and $z = 1 + \frac{7}{1+t}$ for $s, t \ge 0$.

Comment: @jereiko, I'll.

Comment: @haidangel You mean: Find the largest constant $k$ such that: $\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{x}{y}\geq\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{2x}{y+ z} \ge 0$ holds for all $1 \le x, y, z \le k$.

Comment: @haidangel $y = 1$, I have no idea how to parameterize $x, z$ for the range $[1, 8]$ besides this substitutions?

Comment: @haidangel I think that $k_{\max} \approx 8.070311631$, using the substitution.

Comment: Yes, it's already in the result on Wolfram|Alpha.

Comment: what's wrong with your wolfram solution?

Comment: @dezdichado, it's a result, it's not a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eliminating denominators, we arrive to the inequality $\;f(x,y,z)\ge 0,\;$ where
$$\begin{align}
&f(x,y,z) = x^3 y^3 + y^3 z^3 + x^3 z^3 - 3 x^2 y^2 z^2
\\[4pt]&
 + x^2 y^4 + y^2 z^4 + z^2 x^4 - x^4 y z - x y^4 z - x y z^4.
\end{align}\tag1$$
Since $(1)$ is homogenius and has the rotational symmetry, then WLOG there are two possible cases:

- $\mathbf{1=x\le y \le z}.\;$ Assume $\;y=1+u,\; z=y+v,\;$ then
  $$\begin{align}
  &f(1,1+u,1+u+v)=u^4(v^2+v)+u^3(5v^3+11v^2+7v+2)
  \\[4pt]&
  +u^2(9v^4+30v^3+33v^2+15v+4)
  +u(7v^5+30v^4+44v^3+25v^2+4v)
  \\[4pt]&
  +2v^6+10v^5+18v^4+14v^3+4v^2 \ge0,
  \end{align}$$
  and **the case is proved.**
- $\mathbf{1=z\le y\le x\le 1+p}.\;$ Assume $\;y=1+pv,\; x=1+p,\;$ then

$$\begin{align}
&g(p,v)=\dfrac1{p^2}f(1+p,1+pv,1) = (p^4+p^3)v^4+(p^4+7p^3+7p^2+2p)v^3
\\[4pt]&
+(3p^3+12p^2+9p+4)v^2+(-p^3-p^2+p-4)v+2p+4.
\end{align}\tag2$$
If $\;v=\dfrac1p,\;p\to\infty,\;$ then the given inequality does not satisfy.

If $\;\mathbf{p=7},\;$ then
$$g(7,v) = 18 -389v+1684v^2+5159v^3+2744v^4
$$$$
=(18+43v)(1-12v)^2 +13(3v-14v^2)^2 + 7v^2+59v^3+196v^4 \ge 0,$$
and **the case is proved.**

**The greatest value** of $\;p\;$ can be defined from the system $\;g'_v =g=0,\;$
with the numerical solution $\;p\approx7.07031\,16307,\; v\approx 0.08248\,18190.\;$

**The best constant is 8.07031 16307.**

Comment: I remember that the best constant is on the Wolfram|Alpha result and the homogenous subsitution required.

Comment: But your solution is great.