# Is there a simple criterion for when $e^{x}+ ax^{2}+ bx+ c$ has a zero?

Tags: logic, exponential-function, model-theory, discriminant, decidability

> Is there a simple criterion for when
> $$e^{x}+ ax^{2}+ bx+ c$$
> has a zero ?
> Source: MathOverflow/@MattF.

*one* simpler function $e^{x}+ ax+ b$ has a zero iff either or $- a+ a\!\ln\!\left ( -a \right )+ b\!\leq 0>\!a,$ or $a\!= 0>\!b,$ or $a> 0,$ where the last clause comes from using calculus to minimize the function.
**First edit**. It might be possible to extract something from Wilkie's approach in his
paper "Model completeness results for expansions of the ordered field of real numbers by restricted Pfaffian functions and the exponential function," which implies, among other things, that there is a system of exponential equations and inequalities that has a solution iff $e^{x}+ ax^{2}+ bx+ c$ doesn't.
**Second edit**. There is an algorithm to determine whether $e^{x}+ ax^{2}+ bx+ c$ has a zero :
simultaneously check for each positive rational $q$ whether $e^{q}+ aq^{2}+ bq+ c< 0,$ for each $n$ whether for all the positives $x$ so that $ax^{2}+ bx+ c+ \sum_{k= 0}^{n}\frac{x^{k}}{k!}\geq 0,$ and something similar for the negatives $x.$ The first piece comes from the proof of the transcendence of $e,$ like_ https://mathoverflow.net/a/378064/164469, and the second is standard Tarski-Seidenberg quantifier elimination. But this algorithm does not provide a time bound for the algorithm or a single set of discriminants which can be used for all $a, b, c.$

Comment: Yes, $\{a,b,c \} \in \mathbb{R}$, then $x$ can have real and complex values, plot the function to see...... To find it's zeros, you'll use numerical approximation, for the complex values you alter the equation

Comment: @AderinsolaJoshua, thanks a real lot, but you said "numerical approximation," does there exist no such a type like the discriminant of special functions ??

Comment: Probably a result analogous to the one for $e^x + a x + b$ can be stated in terms of the Lambert W-function. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function

Comment: @TravisWillse, this article inspired me, I had thought of that I had to find a so-called general discriminant of special functions before, well, it's the strongest method_ https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4035405/822157, to me. I forgot that we also have many ways to approach.

Comment: I wonder if [MetiTarski](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~lp15/papers/Arith) could do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's one of my first answers, so my MathJax and my answer won't be perfect. I appreciate every help.

I am not sure if my answer is correct, because the first answer has many likes and an easier criterium. However, when graphing the function, it doesn't seem to work for me.

I've gone the same way. It is the question for which $a, b, c$ are the functions $f(x)=e^x$ and $g(x)=-ax^2 -bx -c$ intersect. $a<0$ is trivial, so we will assume $a>0.$

The function $g(x)$ is concave and the function $f(x)$ is convex, so we will look at the argument, where both functions have the same derivative. If $f=g$ at that point, there is exactly one intersection. If $f>g,$ there is no intersection and when $f<g$ there are two intersections.

Set $f'(k)=g'(k)$ to get the desired argument. If you solve $$e^k = -2ak-b$$ you get
$$k=-W(\frac{e^{- \frac{b}{2a} }}{2a})- \frac {b}{2a}$$

There are zeroes, when $e^k \leq -ak^2 -bk-c.\,k$ is the root of the above, so we can substitute $e^k.$

We get :
$$-2ak-b\leq -ak^2-bk-c$$

So the answer to your question is $:\quad h(x)=e^x+ax^2+bx+c$ has zeroes, iff $$ak^2+(b-2a)k-b+c\leq 0$$ or $$a<0$$ with $k$ being the term at the top. One zero with equality and two zeroes with strict inequality.

Comment: Thanks a rl lot

Comment: I just solved the equation in k by hand and you can also take $k=ln(2a W(...))$ With the same term in the Lambert W function as in the other expression for k. Thanks for the edit!

Comment: I'm so obliged.

Answer (score 2):

You basically ask when

$f(x)=e^x+c$ and $g(x)=-ax^2-bx=-x(ax+b)$ cross each other.

Always when $a < 0$.

For $a \geq 0$ it is as follows.

The reason we have chosen the above two functions is that it is easier to visualize what is going on. $g(x)$ has one of the legs through the origin and $e^x$ is elevated by $c$. For such arrangement, there is one critical value $c_0$ when $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are touching each other. Then, if $c > c_0$, $f(x)$ cannot cross $g(x)$ or if $c < c_0$ they will have two intersections.

When $f(x)$ is touching $g(x)$ it is at that point $f'(x_0)=g'(x_0)$ giving us the condition:

$$e^{x_0}=-2 a x_0 - b$$

which we can effectively solve and find $x_0$. Another condition we are getting from replacing $e^{x_0}$ into $f(x_0)=g(x_0)$ which is a common point.

$$-2 a x_0 - b+c_0=-ax_0^2-bx_0$$

giving

$$c_0=-ax_0^2-bx_0+2 a x_0 + b$$

So the condition is

$$c < c_0=-ax_0^2 +(2 a-b) x_0 + b \text{ for } x_0 = -W(\frac{e^{\frac{-b}{2a}}}{2a}) - \frac{b}{2 a}$$

If $a = 0$ we have always the solution if $b>0$ and otherwise

$$e^{x_0}= - b, x_0=\ln(-b)$$

$$c_0=b-bx_0$$

or $$c < b(1-\ln(-b)), b<0$$

If $a = b = 0$ we have the solution only if $c < 0$.

Comment: Do you say, if $4a^2+b^2≥4ac$ then the equation always has a zero?

Comment: If $a=b=c=1$ which is correct for $4a^2+b^2≥4ac$ do you say the equation $e^x+x^2+x+1$ has a real zero?