# Stronger than Nesbitt's inequality $\frac{a}{\sqrt[4]{8(b^4+c^4)}}+\frac{b}{a+c}+\frac{c}{a+b}\geq\frac{3}{2}$

Tags: inequality, contest-math, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

> Let $a$, $b$ and $c$ be non-negative numbers such that $ab+ac+bc\neq0$. Prove that:
>   $$\frac{a}{\sqrt[4]{8(b^4+c^4)}}+\frac{b}{a+c}+\frac{c}{a+b}\geq\frac{3}{2}$$

Nesbitt's inequality is the following:

Let $a$, $b$ and $c$ be non-negative numbers such that $ab+ac+bc\neq0$. Prove that:
$$\frac{a}{b+c}+\frac{b}{a+c}+\frac{c}{a+b}\geq\frac{3}{2},$$
which follows from C-S:
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{a}{b+c}=\sum_{cyc}\frac{a^2}{ab+ac}\geq\frac{(a+b+c)^2}{\sum\limits_{cyc}(ab+ac)}=\frac{(a+b+c)^2}{2(ab+ac+bc)}\geq\frac{3}{2},$$
but this way does not help for the starting inequality.

There is a nice solution for the following inequality, which was in our test six months ago.

Let $a$, $b$ and $c$ be positive numbers. Prove that:
$$\frac{a}{\sqrt[3]{4(b^3+c^3)}}+\frac{b}{c+a}+\frac{c}{a+b}\ge \frac{3}{2}$$

By C-S $$\frac{b}{c+a}+\frac{c}{a+b}\geq\frac{(b+c)^2}{ab+ac+2bc}.$$
Thus, it's enough to prove that
$$\frac{a}{\sqrt[3]{4(b^3+c^3)}}+\frac{(b+c)^2}{ab+ac+2bc}\geq\frac{3}{2}$$ or
$$2(b+c)a^2-(3(b+c)\sqrt[3]{4(b^3+c^3)}-4bc)a+2(b^2-bc+c^2)\sqrt[3]{4(b^3+c^3)}\geq0.$$
Thus, it's enough to prove that
$$16(b+c)(b^2-bc+c^2)\sqrt[3]{4(b^3+c^3)}\geq\left(3(b+c)\sqrt[3]{4(b^3+c^3)}-4bc\right)^2$$ or
$$16\sqrt[3]{4(b^3+c^3)^4}\geq\left(3(b+c)\sqrt[3]{4(b^3+c^3)}-4bc\right)^2$$ and since
$$3(b+c)\sqrt[3]{4(b^3+c^3)}>4bc,$$
it remains to prove that
$$4\sqrt[3]{2(b^3+c^3)^2}\geq3(b+c)\sqrt[3]{4(b^3+c^3)}-4bc$$ and after using
$$x^3+y^3+z^3-3xyz=(x+y+z)(x^2+y^2+z^2-xy-xz-yz),$$ where
$$x^2+y^2+z^2-xy-xz-yz\neq0$$ we need to prove that
$$128(b^3+c^3)^2-108(b+c)^3(b^3+c^3)+64b^3c^3+288(b+c)(b^3+c^3)bc\geq0.$$
Now, let $b^2+c^2=2kbc$.
Hence, we need to prove that:
$$128(2k+2)(2k-1)^2-108(2k+2)^2(2k-1)+64+288(2k+2)(2k-1)\geq0$$ or
$$(k-1)^2(10k+11)\geq0.$$
Done!

But this way gives a wrong inequality again.

Comment: from where does it come?

Comment: @Dr. Sonnhard Graubner It's my problem.

Comment: oh nice i will try it

Comment: Perhaps the following may be true, but this is just a mere speculation: $$\forall n \in \mathbb{Z^+}, \ \frac{a}{\big(2^{n - 1}(b^n + c^n)\big)^{1/n}} + \frac{b}{a + c} + \frac{c}{a + b} \geqslant \frac{3}{2}$$

Comment: For $n=5$ it's wrong already.

Comment: I think I have the keys of this inequality with two substitutions do you want to collaborate with me again ?

Comment: I also have very many keys, but I have no a proof of this inequality. Delete please your joke here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2732128

Comment: I have a proof using karamata inequality do you accept this ?

Comment: It was your joke? I think it's impossible to prove this inequality by Karamata.

Comment: If the equation is true for $n=3, 4$ and wrong for $n=5$, then what would be the smallest upper bound of real number $n$ satisfying the equation?

Comment: A speculation of mine: $$\frac{a}{\sqrt [4] {8(b^4+c^4)}}+\frac{b}{\sqrt [4] {8(a^4+c^4)}}+\frac{c}{\sqrt [4] {8(a^4+b^4)}}\leqslant \frac 32$$ with equality if and only if $a=b=c=1$.

Comment: @user477343: Did you do some simulation to support your hypothesis? Unless I made an error, that term is <3/2 for (a, b, c) = (1, 1, 0) and >3/2 for (a, b, c) = (1, 2, 5).

Comment: @MartinR well at the moment I was testing with $b = a + 1$ and $c = a+2$. Perhaps I can re-write my speculation as follows: $$\forall a\in\mathbb{N}, \ \frac{a}{\sqrt [4] {8\big((a+1)^4+(a+2)^4\big)}} + \frac{a+1}{\sqrt [4] {8\big(a^4 + (a+2)^4\big)}} + \frac{a+2}{\sqrt [4] {8\big((a^4 + (a+1)^4\big)}}\leqslant \frac 32$$

Comment: The bounty solution is wrong, and this is evident from the comments

Comment: @Yuri Negometyanov I agree with you. It's total wrong.

Comment: It should be fixed

Comment: I don't understand why it was accepted furthermore my proof is partial it's a shame I think , but I will fix this. (+1) Yuri !

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg And what do you think about my solution?=)

Comment: @FatsWallers What do you think about bounty?

Comment: I think you want to say "totally wrong", and you don't know "totally wrong" is abusive expression. And  @max8128 you should use @.

Answer (score 4):

The task is homogenius and symmetric by the $b,c.$

Let WLOG
$$a=1,\quad s = \dfrac{b+c}2,\quad t=\left(\dfrac{b-c}{b+c}\right)^2,\tag1$$
then
\begin{align}
&b+c = 2s,\quad bc = s^2(1-t),\quad b^2+c^2=2s^2(1+t),\\[4pt]
&b^4+c^4 = (b^2+c^2)^2 - 2(bc)^2 = 2s^4(t^2+6t+1),\\[4pt]
&\dfrac{b}{1+c}+\dfrac{c}{1+b} = \dfrac{b+c+b^2+c^2}{1+b+c+bc} = \dfrac{2s+2s^2(1+t)}{1+2s+s^2(1-t)},
\end{align}
and the issue task transforms to
$$\dfrac1{s\sqrt[4]{t^2+6t+1}} + \dfrac{4s+4s^2(1+t)}{1+s+s^2(1-t)} \ge 3, \quad s > 0,\quad 1\ge t\ge0,$$
or
$$\dfrac1{s\sqrt[4]{t^2+6t+1}} + 4\dfrac{(1+s)(1+2s)}{(1+s)^2-s^2t} \ge 7, \quad s > 0,\quad 1\ge t\ge0,$$
or
$$\dfrac{v-1}{\sqrt[4]{t^2+6t+1}} + 4\dfrac{v(v+1)}{v^2-t} \ge 7, \quad v > 1,\quad 1\ge t\ge0, \tag2,$$
where
$$v=\dfrac1s+1.\tag3$$
Then, using the evident inequality
$$\sqrt{1\pm x}\le 1\pm \dfrac x2,$$
easy to get
$$\sqrt{1+6t^2+t^4} = (1+3t)\sqrt{1-\dfrac {8t^2}{(1+3t)^2}}\le(1+3t)\left(1-\dfrac{4t^2}{(1+3t)^2}\right) = \dfrac{1+6t+5t^2}{1+3t},$$
$$\sqrt{1+6t+5t^2} = (1+3t)\sqrt{1-\dfrac {4t^2}{(1+3t)^2}}\le\dfrac{1+3t}{1+\dfrac{2t^2}{(1+3t)^2}} = \dfrac{(1+3t)^3}{1+6t+11t^2}.$$

This allows to prove the stronger inequality
$${1+6t+11t^2\over (\sqrt{1+3t\,})^5}(v-1) + 4\dfrac{v(v+1)}{v^2-t} \ge 7, \quad v > 1,\quad 1\ge t\ge0.$$
Substitution
$$z=\sqrt{1+3t}\tag4$$
leads to the equivalent task
$${2-4z^2+11z^4\over 9z^5}(v-1)+12{v(v+1)\over 3v^2 + 1-z^2} \ge 7,\quad z\ge 1,\quad 2 \ge z\ge 1,$$
or
$$f(z,v) \ge 0,\quad v>1,\quad 2 \ge z\ge1,\tag5$$
wherein
\begin{align}
f(z,v) = (3v^2+1-z^2)((v-1)(11z^4-4z^2+2)-63z^5)+108z^5(v^2+v).\tag6
\end{align}

The highest value of $f(x)$ can be achieved on its stationary points or the area bounds.

**The stationary points**

The stationary points of $f(z,v)$ can be obtained from the conditions $f'_v=\dfrac1{3z}f'_v=0,$ and that leads to the system

\begin{cases}
(99z^4-36z^2+18)v^2+(-162z^5-66z^4+24z^2-12)v-11z^6+108z^5+15z^4-6z^2+2 = 0\\[4pt]
(44z^2-8)v^3+(-135z^3-44z^2+8)v^2+(-22z^4+180z^3+20z^2-4)v+147z^5+22z^4-105z^3-20z^2+4=0\\[4pt]
v>1,\quad 2 \ge z\ge1,\tag7
\end{cases}
(see also [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=simplify+%7Bdf%2Fdv,+df%2Fdz%7D,+where+f%3D(3v%5E2%2B1-z%5E2)((v-1)(11z%5E4-4z%5E2%2B2)-63z%5E5)%2B108z%5E5(v%5E2%2Bv))), with the [solutions](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7Bdf%2Fdv,+1%2F(3z)+df%2Fdz%7D,+where+f%3D(3v%5E2%2B1-z%5E2)((v-1)(11z%5E4-4z%5E2%2B2)-63z%5E5)%2B108z%5E5(v%5E2%2Bv))

$$\begin{pmatrix}v\\z\\f(v,z)\end{pmatrix}
=\left\{
\begin{pmatrix}2\\1\\0\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix}\approx 1.713140\\\approx 0.883476\\ \approx 0.0969191\end{pmatrix}
\right\}\tag8$$
which can be obtained using [the polynomial reduction way](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1775498/x-y-z-geqslant-0-xy2z3-1-prove-x2yy2zz2x-frac12/1801630#1801630).

Taking in account the calculations accuracy, this means that $f(v,z)\ge 0$ in the stationary points.

**The bounds**

If $\mathbf{v=1,}$ then $f(1,z) = 9z^5(7z^2-4)\ge 0\text{ if } z\in[1,2].$

If $\mathbf{z=1},$ then $f(v, 1) = 27v(v-2)^2 \ge 0 \text{ if } v\in(1,\infty).$

If $\mathbf{z=2},$ then 
$f(v,2) = 54 (11 - 3 v)^2 (v + 1) \ge 0,\text{ if } v\in(1,\infty).$

These mean that $f(v,z)\ge 0$ on the area $v\in(1, \infty), \quad z\in [1,2].$

**Proved.**

---

*Update 08.05.2018*

**The polynomial reduction way**

Taking in account the elder coefficients of the derivatives, let us consider the system
$$\dfrac{df}{dv} = 4v(11z^2-2)\dfrac{df}{dv} - \dfrac{-33z^4+12z^2-6}{z}\dfrac{df}{dz} = 0,$$
or
$$-6(27z^5+11z^4-4z^2+2)v+9(11z^4-4z^2+2)v^2 = 11z^6-108z^5-15z^4+6z^2-2\\
2(847z^8-6534z^7-1012z^6+2808z^5+564z^4-1620z^3-184z^2+28)v+ 3(2079z^7+484z^6-1188z^5-264z^4+810z^3+120z^2-16)v^2 = 9(1617z^9+242z^8-1743z^7-308z^6+714z^5+168z^4-210z^3-56z^2+8)
$$
$$\begin{cases}
-6(27z^5+11z^4-4z^2+2)v + 9(11z^4-4z^2+2)v^2=11z^6-108z^5-15z^4+6z^2-2\\[4pt]
2(847z^8-6534z^7-1012z^6+2808z^5+564z^4-1620z^3-184z^2+28)v\\
+3(2079z^7+484z^6-1188z^5-264z^4+810z^3+120z^2-16)v^2\\
=9(1617z^9+242z^8-1743z^7-308z^6+714z^5+168z^4-210z^3-56z^2+8)\\[4pt]
v>1,\quad 2 \ge z\ge1,
\end{cases}\tag9$$
(see also [Wolfram Alfa](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=simplify%20%7Bdf%2Fdv,%20df%2Fdz%7D.%7B%7B1,4v(11z%5E2-2)%7D,%7B0,(-33z%5E4%2B12z%5E2-6)%2Fz%7D%7D,%20where%20f%3D(3v%5E2%2B1-z%5E2)((v-1)(11z%5E4-4z%5E2%2B2)-63z%5E5)%2B108z%5E5(v%5E2%2Bv)))
which [can consist the additional roots](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7Bdf%2Fdv,%20df%2Fdz%7D.%7B%7B1,4v(11z%5E2-2)%7D,%7B0,(-33z%5E4%2B12z%5E2-6)%2Fz%7D%7D,%20where%20f%3D(3v%5E2%2B1-z%5E2)((v-1)(11z%5E4-4z%5E2%2B2)-63z%5E5)%2B108z%5E5(v%5E2%2Bv)) besides the roots of $(7).$
Consideraton of $(9)$ as the linear by $\{s, s^2\}$ leads to the solution
$$\begin{pmatrix} v\\ v^2\end{pmatrix} = 
\dfrac1{\Delta}\begin{pmatrix} \Delta_1\\ \Delta_2\end{pmatrix},\tag{10}$$
where
\begin{align}
\Delta&=
\begin{vmatrix}
-6(27z^5+11z^4-4z^2+2)&9(11z^4-4z^2+2)\\[4pt]
\genfrac{.}{.}{0}{0}{2(847z^8-6534z^7-1012z^6+2808z^5}{+564z^4-1620z^3-184z^2+28)}
&\genfrac{.}{.}{0}{0}{3(2079z^7+484z^6}{-1188z^5-264z^4+810z^3+120z^2-16)}
\end{vmatrix}\\[4pt]
&=-18(65450z^{12}-35937z^{11}-41272z^{10}+28512z^9+28976z^8-21060z^7\\
&-2960z^6+6048z^5+988z^4-1620z^3-176z^2+24),\\
\end{align}
$$\Delta = -18d(z),\tag{11}$$
$$\begin{align}
d&=65450z^{12}-35937z^{11}-41272z^{10}+28512z^9+28976z^8-21060z^7\\
&-2960z^6+6048z^5+988z^4-1620z^3-176z^2+24,
\end{align}\tag{12}$$
\begin{align}
\Delta_1&=
\begin{vmatrix}
11z^6-108z^5-15z^4+6z^2+2&9(11z^4-4z^2+2)\\[4pt]
\genfrac{.}{.}{0}{0}{9(1617z^9+242z^8-1743z^7-308z^6}{+714z^5+168z^4-210z^3-56z^2+8)}
&\genfrac{.}{.}{0}{0}{3(2079z^7+484z^6-1188z^5}{-264z^4+810z^3+120z^2-16)}
\end{vmatrix}\\[4pt]
&=-6(228690z^{13}+145541z^{12}-297891z^{11}-117876z^{10}+209952z^9+87762z^8\\
&-102762z^7-24408z^6+28512z^5+8532z^4-6480z^3-2016z^2+232),\\
\end{align}
$$\Delta_1=-6d_1(z),\tag{13}$$
$$\begin{align}
d_1(z)&=228690z^{13}+145541z^{12}-297891z^{11}-117876z^{10}+209952z^9+87762z^8\\
&-102762z^7-24408z^6+28512z^5+8532z^4-6480z^3-2016z^2+232,
\end{align}\tag{14}$$
\begin{align}
\Delta_2&=
\begin{vmatrix}
-6(27z^5+11z^4-4z^2+2)&11z^6-108z^5-15z^4+6z^2+2\\[4pt]
\genfrac{.}{.}{0}{0}{2(847z^8-6534z^7-1012z^6+2808z^5}{+564z^4-1620z^3-184z^2+28)}
&\genfrac{.}{.}{0}{0}{9(1617z^9+242z^8-1743z^7-308z^6}{+714z^5+168z^4-210z^3-56z^2+8)}
\end{vmatrix},\\[4pt]
&=-2(1188110z^{14}+493317z^{13}-516938z^{12}-678645z^{11}+126096z^{10}+450036z^9\\
&+103236z^8-226476z^7-46980z^6+59940z^5+17100z^4-14580z^3-4088z^2+488).\\
\end{align}
$$\Delta_2 = -2d_2(z),\tag{15}$$
$$\begin{align}
d_2(z)&=1188110z^{14}+493317z^{13}-516938z^{12}-678645z^{11}+126096z^{10}+450036z^9\\
&+103236z^8-226476z^7-46980z^6+59940z^5+17100z^4-14580z^3-4088z^2+488,\\
\end{align}\tag{16}$$
$(10),(12),(14),(16)$ allow to write
$$v=\dfrac{d_1(z)}{3d(z)},\quad d_1(z)^2 = d_2(z)d(z),$$
or
$$
\begin{cases}
76977054000z^{25}-25462683400z^{26}-14469601850z^{24}-128299931694z^{23}+\\
47986668444z^{22}+144016029432z^{21}-67667920532z^{20}-106475101020z^{19}+\\
50533574480z^{18}+61655670720z^{17}-26340071868z^{16}-27611975304z^{15}+\\
9481920960z^{14}+10104266592z^{13}-2350471584z^{12}-3006244368z^{11}+331237872z^{10}+\\721643904z^9+10846384z^8-136453248z^7-19240960z^6+\\
17418240z^5+5038080z^4-1140480z^3-563776z^2+30976=0\\
v=\dfrac{d_1(z)}{3d(z)},
v>1,\quad 2 \ge z\ge1.
\end{cases}\tag{17}$$
The first equation allows partial decomposition to the form of
$$\begin{align}
&(z-1)(11z^4-4z^2+2)\times\\
&(1157394700z^{21}-2341562300z^{20}-1262982325z^{19}+3296484752z^{18} +1297048050z^{17}\\
&-2954973078z^{16}-802331850z^{15}+1662261954z^{14}+511593870z^{13}-621625938z^{12}\\
&-234164016z^{11}+160737876z^{10}+79849092z^9-29795100z^8-22817208z^7+2159304z^6\\
&+4347504z^5+563184z^4-402832z^3-117712z^2+7744z+7744),
\end{align}\tag{18}$$
where the last polynomial factor has the roots
$$\begin{align}
&z\in\{-0.65254852+0.411596443i,\quad
-0.65254852-0.411596443i,\quad
-0.533266085,\\
&-0.463163014+0.296052158i,\quad
-0.463163014-0.296052158i,\\
&-0.423458642-0.209546484i,\quad
-0.423458642+0.209546484i,\\
&-0.242560904-0.338675996i,\quad
-0.242560904+0.338675996i,\\
&-0.220398679-0.318470135i,\quad
-0.220398679+0.318470135i,\\
&0.334079252+0.005204691i,\quad
0.334079252-0.005204691i,\\
&0.397903595+0.409264586i,\quad
0.397903595-0.409264586i,\\
&0.553362795-0.024077867i,\quad
0.553362795+0.024077867i,\\
&0.658848407+0.496670038i,\quad
0.658848407-0.496670038i,\\
&0.883475687,\quad 1.788793855\}.\\
\end{align}$$
Easy to see that this leads to the result $(8).$

Comment: If you made the *slightest* mistake, everything would be wrong. $(+1)$

Comment: @user477343 I've tried to simplify the equation further, but the coefficients only increased.

Comment: I'm impressed by the amount of work, whether or not there is an error.

Answer (score 0):

Your inequality is equivalent to :
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{(8(x^4+h^4))^{0.25}}+\frac{x}{h+1}+\frac{h}{x+1}$$
Here we assume that $x\geq h \geq 1$

It's easy to see that the function $f(x)$ is convex with $h$ fixed (as the sum of convexs functions) and increasing for $x\geq h$
Furthermore for $h$ fixed we have that the minimum is inferior to $h$ (in abscissa)

So we have :

$$f(x)\geq f(h)$$

We get :
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{(8(x^4+h^4))^{0.25}}+\frac{x}{h+1}+\frac{h}{x+1}\geq\frac{1}{(8(h^4+h^4))^{0.25}}+\frac{h}{h+1}+\frac{h}{h+1} $$

So the inequality is verified in this case because it's easy to threat this one variable inequality.

The case where $h\geq x \geq 1$ is the same (because of the symetry) and the cases $x\geq 1 \geq h$ and

$h\geq 1 \geq x$ are similar for the same reasons

Now we continue with the case $x\leq h \leq 1$

Remark that if we inverse each variable it becomes :

$$\frac{xh}{(8(x^4+h^4))^{0.25}}+\frac{x}{h+1}+\frac{h}{x+1}$$

With $h\geq 1$ and $x\geq 1$ but we have :

$$\frac{xh}{(8(x^4+h^4))^{0.25}}+\frac{x}{h+1}+\frac{h}{x+1}\geq \frac{1}{(8(x^4+h^4))^{0.25}}+\frac{x}{h+1}+\frac{h}{x+1}\geq 1.5$$

So this case is verified .

Done !

Edit :My proof is incomplete like this because the case where  $x\geq 1 \geq h$ is not solved . So I purpose to you a solution :

The main idea is to use the three chord lemma related to the convexity of the function $f(x)$ so we have for $x\geq \sqrt{x}\geq x^{0.25}$ :

$$\frac{f(x)-f(\sqrt{x})}{x-\sqrt{x}}\geq \frac{f(x)-f(x^{0.25})}{x-x^{0.25}} \geq \frac{f(\sqrt{x})-f(x^{0.25})}{\sqrt{x}-x^{0.25}}$$

We can apply this inequality $n$ times to get :

$$\frac{f(x)-f(\sqrt{x})}{x-\sqrt{x}}\geq \frac{f(x^{1/2^n})-f(x^{1/2^{n+1}})}{x^{1/2^n}-x^{1/2^{n+1}}}$$ 
But we have to prove that the RHS is positive for a variable wich tends to $1$ so we get the following result to evaluate :

$$\lim_{x\to 1} \frac{\dfrac{1}{(8(x^{1/2^n}+h^4))^{0.25}}+\dfrac{x^{1/2^n}}{h+1} + \dfrac{h}{x^{1/2^n}+1}- \left(\dfrac{1}{(8(x^{1/2^{n+1}}+h^4))^{0.25}} + \dfrac{x^{1/2^{n+1}}}{h+1}+\dfrac{h}{x^{1/2^{n+1}}+1} \right)}{x^{1/2^n}-x^{1/2^{n+1}}}$$

For that see the the interesting answer of G.Cab [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2767877/question-about-a-limit)

With this answer we know that the result does not depends on $n$ and is equal to :

$$
\eqalign{
  & \mathop { }
  &   {1 \over {h + 1}} - {1 \over {2^{\,11/4} \left( {h^{\,4}  + 1} \right)^{\,5/4} }} - {h \over 4} \cr} 
$$

Quantity wich is positive for $h\leq 1$

So we get :

$$\frac{f(x)-f(\sqrt{x})}{x-\sqrt{x}}\geq 0$$

Or :

$$f(x)\geq f(\sqrt{x})$$

If we apply this inequality $n$ times we get :

$$f(x)\geq f(x^{\frac{1}{2^n}})$$

But the variable tends $1$ and the RHS to $1.5$ so we get the desired result !

Comment: @max1828 Does it work  for n=5? =)

Comment: Yes it works with the coefiicient $8$ why ? There is a mistake in my reasoning ?

Comment: @max1828 Inequality with $n=5$ and coefficient $16$ should be wrong

Comment: See attentively my answer . With the inequality withe one variable we can see that it works for large value . I will post a question about this .Thanks for your interest !

Comment: The proposed "proof" is erroneous. Try to find the error yourself.

Comment: @max1828 Ok. Let $x=16, h=9.$ Are you sure that $4 > 9?$ At that time, you have silently used this claim in the second step of the first  part of the "proof".

Comment: This "solution" is total wrong. Why it was accepted?

Comment: why is this one has bounty?

Comment: Now it works and it's simple and elegant !

Answer (score 0):

With computer, here is a solution.

WLOG, assume that $b \ge c$.

(1) If $c = 0$, we need to prove that 
$$\frac{a}{2^{3/4}b} + \frac{b}{a} \ge \frac{3}{2}.$$
Using AM-GM, we have $\frac{a}{2^{3/4}b} + \frac{b}{a} \ge 
2\sqrt{\frac{a}{2^{3/4}b} \frac{b}{a}} = 2^{5/8} > \frac{3}{2}$. The inequality is true.

(2) If $c > 0$, WLOG, assume that $c=1$. 
Let $b = 1 + x, \ x \ge 0$. We need to prove that
$$\frac{a}{\sqrt[4]{8((1+x)^4+1)}} + \frac{1+x}{a+1} + \frac{1}{a+1+x} \ge \frac{3}{2}.$$

We will use the following bound:
$$\frac{4(1+x)^2(165x^2+144x+112)}{389x^3+734x^2+624x+224} \ge \sqrt[4]{8((1+x)^4+1)}, \quad \forall x\ge 0$$
which follows from
\begin{align}
&\Big(\frac{4(1+x)^2(165x^2+144x+112)}{389x^3+734x^2+624x+224}\Big)^4 - 8((1+x)^4+1)\\
=\ & \frac{8x^6}{(389x^3+734x^2+624x+224)^4}\\
&\times \left(820374959x^{10}+8129708452x^9+34536522338x^8+88010431212x^7\right.\\
&\quad +150840675678x^6+183012461808x^5 + 160216957296x^4+100447002624x^3\\
&\quad \left. +43418651136x^2+11761455104x+1518727168\right).
\end{align}
Thus, it suffices to prove that
$$\frac{a(389x^3+734x^2+624x+224)}{4(1+x)^2(165x^2+144x+112)} + \frac{1+x}{a+1} + \frac{1}{a+1+x} \ge \frac{3}{2}.$$
After clearing the denominators, it suffices to prove that
$$q_3a^3 + q_2a^2 + q_1 a + q_0 \ge 0$$
where
\begin{align}
q_3 &= 389 x^3+734 x^2+624 x+224\\
q_2 &= -601 x^4-1332 x^3-1298 x^2-736 x-224\\
q_1 &= -330 x^5-1219 x^4-1903 x^3-1638 x^2-848 x-224, \\
q_0 &= 660 x^6+2226 x^5+3538 x^4+3550 x^3+2314 x^2+960 x+224.
\end{align}

If $x=0$, we have $q_3a^3 + q_2a^2 + q_1 a + q_0 = 224(a+1)(a-1)^2 \ge 0$. True.

If $x > 0$, let $f(u) = q_3u^3 + q_2u^2 + q_1 u + q_0$.
The discriminant of $f(u)$ is
\begin{align}
&\mathrm{discr}(f) = -(1+x)^2x^4 \\
&\times \left(194821434060 x^{12}+1160408972196 x^{11}+3444683967175 x^{10}+6771294350288 x^9 \right.\\
&\quad +9755714292752 x^8+10819604233984 x^7+9460649716736 x^6+6565740839936 x^5\\
&\quad +3594172926976 x^4+1515569807360 x^3+468531445760 x^2\\
&\quad \left. +95759892480 x+9441116160\right).
\end{align}
Since $\mathrm{discr}(f) < 0$, the equation $f(u)=0$ has only one real root.
Note also that $f(0) = q_0 > 0$ and $f(-\infty) = -\infty$ (since $q_3>0$). Thus, the only one real root of $f(u)=0$ is negative. Thus, $f(a) > 0$ for $a \ge 0$. We are done.