# prove this inequality by $abc=1$

Tags: inequality, polynomials, substitution, symmetric-polynomials, buffalo-way

Let $a,b,c>0$ and $abc=1$,show that
$$(a^{10}+b^{10}+c^{10})^2\ge 3(a^{14}+b^{14}+c^{14})$$

since
$$LHS=\sum \left(a^{20}+\dfrac{2}{a^{10}}\right)$$
it is prove
$$\sum_{cyc}\left(a^{20}+\dfrac{2}{a^{10}}-3a^{14}\right)\ge 0$$ not easy,and I found $x^{20}+2x^{-10}-3x^{14}$http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E(20)%2B2x%5E(-10)-3x%5E(14)

[image]

Comment: A [closer look](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+x%5E20%2B2x%5E(-10)-3x%5E14,+x%3D+0.9+to+1.1) reveals that $x^{20}+\dfrac2{x^{10}}-3x^{14}\geqslant0$ is false.

Comment: Shouldn't there be a $3$ in front of the term $a^{14}$ in the last sum?

Comment: This is problem 12024 from the *American Mathematical Monthly*. It is still current: http://www.mat.uniroma2.it/~tauraso/AMM/amm.html

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Your version has an exponent $13$ rather than $14$ in the right-hand side.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown,it's different it

Comment: I very much doubt that the problem has exponent 14 on the right side. With the following substitution: $a=\sqrt{x}, b=\sqrt{y}, c=\sqrt{z}$ the problem becomes simpler: $(x^5+y^5+z^5)^2 \ge 3 (x^7+y^7+z^7)$ with the same condition ($xyz=1$)

Answer (score 2):

We can use the Vasc's EV-Method, Corollary 1.8 (b):

https://www.emis.de/journals/JIPAM/images/059_06_JIPAM/059_06.pdf

Indeed, we need to prove that:
$$(x^5+y^5+z^5)^2\geq3xyz(x^7+y^7+z^7),$$ where $x$, $y$ and $z$ they are positives.

Now, let $x^5+y^5+z^5=constant$ and $x^7+y^7+z^7=constant.$

Thus, $xyz$ gets a maximal value for equality case of two variables

and since the last inequality is homogeneous, it's enough to assume $y=z=1$, which gives
$$(x-1)^2(x^8+2x^7-2x^5-4x^4-2x^3+2x+4)\geq0$$ or
$$(x-1)^2((x^4-2)^2+2x(x^2-1)(x^4-1))\geq0.$$
Done!

Also, the BW helps (https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/buffalo-way/info), but it's a very complicated solution:

Let $x=\min\{x,y,z\}$, $y=x+u$ and $z=x+v$.

Hence, $$(x^5+y^5+z^5)^2-3xyz(x^7+y^7+z^7)=(u^2-uv+v^2)x^8-8(u^3-2u^2v-2uv^2+v^3)x^7+$$
$$+4(5u^4-17u^3v+50u^2v^2-17uv^3+5v^4)x^6+$$
$$+8(11u^5-20u^4v+25u^3v^2+25u^2v^3-20uv^4+11v^5)x^5+$$
$$+2(63u^6-79u^5v+50u^4v^2+100u^3v^3+50u^2v^4-79uv^5+63v^6)x^4+$$
$$+4(24u^7-21u^6v+5u^5v^2+25u^4v^3+25u^3v^4+5u^2v^5-21uv^6+24v^7)x^3+$$
$$+(42u^8-24u^7v+20u^5v^3+50u^4v^4+20u^3v^5-24uv^7+42v^8)x^2+$$
$$+(10u^9-3u^8v+10u^5v^4+10u^4v^5-3uv^8+10v^9)x+(u^5+v^5)^2\geq0$$
because for this it's enough to prove that $$4(u^3-2u^2v-2uv^2+v^3)^2-(u^2-uv+v^2)(5u^4-17u^3v+50u^2v^2-17uv^3+5v^4)\leq0,$$
which is true.

Indeed, let $u^2+v^2=2kuv$.

Thus, $k\geq1$ and we need to prove that
$$4(u^2+2uv+v^2)(u^2-3uv+v^2)^2\leq(u^2-uv+v^2)(5(u^4+v^4)-17uv(u^2+v^2)+50u^2v^2)$$ or
$$8(k+1)(2k-3)^2\leq(2k-1)(5(4k^2-2)-34k+50)$$ or
$$4k^3-12k^2+69k-56\geq0,$$ which is obvious for $k\geq1$.

Also, we can use SOS here.

Indeed, $$(x^5+y^5+z^5)^2-3xyz(x^7+y^7+z^7)=\sum_{cyc}(x^{10}+2x^5y^5-3x^8yz)=$$
$$=\sum_{cyc}\left(x^{10}+x^7y^3+x^7z^3-3x^8yz+2x^5y^5-x^7y^3-x^7z^3\right)=$$
$$=(x^7+y^7+z^7)(x^3+y^3+z^3-3xyz)-\sum_{cyc}x^3y^3(x^2-y^2)^2=$$
$$=\sum_{cyc}(x-y)^2\left(\frac{1}{2}(x+y+z)(x^7+y^7+z^7)-x^3y^3(x+y)^2\right).$$
Now, let $x\geq y\geq z$.

Thus, $$\frac{1}{2}(x+y+z)(x^7+y^7+z^7)\geq\frac{1}{2}(2y+z)(2y^7+z^7)\geq y^3z^3(y+z)^2,$$
$$\frac{1}{2}(x+y+z)(x^7+y^7+z^7)\geq\frac{1}{2}(x+2z)(x^7+2z^7)\geq x^3z^3(x+z)^2$$ and by Muirhead 
$$\sum_{cyc}(x-y)^2\left(\frac{1}{2}(x+y+z)(x^7+y^7+z^7)-x^3y^3(x+y)^2\right)\geq$$
$$\geq(x-y)^2\left(\frac{1}{2}(x+y+z)(x^7+y^7+z^7)-x^3y^3(x+y)^2\right)+$$
$$+(x-z)^2\left(\frac{1}{2}(x+y+z)(x^7+y^7+z^7)-x^3z^3(x+z)^2\right)\geq$$
$$=(x-y)^2\left((x+y+z)(x^7+y^7+z^7)-x^3y^3(x+y)^2-x^3z^3(x+z)^2\right)\geq$$
$$\geq(x-y)^2\left((x^3+y^3+z^3)(x^5+y^5+z^5)-x^3y^3(x+y)^2-x^3z^3(x+z)^2\right)=$$
$$=(x-y)^2\left((x^4+y^4+z^4)^2+\sum_{cyc}x^3y^3(x-y)^3-x^3y^3(x+y)^2-x^3z^3(x+z)^2\right)=$$
$$=(x-y)^2((x^4+y^4+z^4)^2+y^3z^3(y-z)^2-4(y^4+z^4)x^4)\geq$$
$$\geq(x-y)^2((x^4+y^4+z^4)^2-4(y^4+z^4)x^4)=(x-y)^2(x^4-y^4-z^4)^2\geq0.$$
Done!

Comment: I think this equality without EV?

Comment: There is also BW if you wish.

Answer (score 0):

Let us prove the equivalent inequality
$$f(x,y)= \left(x^5y^5+\dfrac1{x^5}+\dfrac1{y^5}\right)^2 -3\left(x^7y^7+\dfrac1{x^7}+\dfrac1{y^7}\right) \ge 0,\quad (x,y)\in\mathbb R_+^2,\tag1$$
the stationary points of which can be defined from the system
$f'_x=0,\ f'_y = 0,$ or
$$\begin{cases}
10\left(x^4y^5-\dfrac1{x^6}\right) \left(x^5y^5+\dfrac1{x^5}+\dfrac1{y^5}\right) -21\left(x^6y^7-\dfrac1{x^8}\right)=0\\
10\left(x^5y^4-\dfrac1{y^6}\right) \left(x^5y^5+\dfrac1{x^5}+\dfrac1{y^5}\right) -21\left(x^7y^6-\dfrac1{y^8}\right)=0,\\
\end{cases}\tag2$$
\begin{align}
&\left(x^4y^5-\dfrac1{x^6}\right)\left(x^7y^6-\dfrac1{y^8}\right) = 
\left(x^5y^4-\dfrac1{y^6}\right)\left(x^6y^7-\dfrac1{x^8}\right),\\[4pt]
&x^2(x^{10}y^5-1)(x^7y^{14}-1) = y^2(x^5y^{10}-1)(x^{14}y^7-1),\\[4pt]
&x^4y^2(1-x^{10}y^5-x^7y^{14}) = y^4x^2(1-x^5y^{10}-x^{14}y^7).\\[4pt]
\end{align}
Let
$$u=x^2y,\quad v=xy^2,$$
then
\begin{align}
&u^2(1-u^5-v^7) = v^2(1-u^7-v^5),\\
&(u-1)(v-1)(v-u)(u^5v+u^5+u^4v^2+2u^4v+u^4\\
&+u^3v^3+2u^3v^2+2u^3v+u^3+u^2v^4+2u^2v^3+2u^2v^2+2u^2v+u^2\\
&+uv^5+2uv^4+2uv^3+2uv^2+2uv+u+v^5+v^4+v^3+v^2+v) = 0
\end{align}
(see also [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=factor%20u%5E2(1-u%5E5-v%5E7)-v%5E2(1-u%5E7-v%5E5))),
\begin{align}
&(u=1)\vee(v=1)\vee(u=v),\\
&(x^2y=1)\vee(xy^2=1)\vee(x^2y=xy^2),\\
\end{align}
$$\left(y=\dfrac1{x^2}\right)\vee\left(x=\dfrac1{y^2}\right)\vee(x=y).\tag3$$

$\mathbf{\text{Case }y=\dfrac1{x^2}}$

Using the second equation of $(2)$ factor $x^8:$
\begin{align}
&10(1-x^{15})(x^{15}+2)-21(x^3-x^{24})=0,\tag4\\
&10(u^{10}+u^5-2)-21(u^8-u) = 0,\quad\text{where}\quad u=x^3,\\
&(u-1)P_9(u)=0,\\
&\text{where the polynomial}\\
&P_9(u) = 10u^9+10u^8-11u^7-11u^6-11u^5-u^4-u^3-u^2-u+20\\
\end{align}
has the single real root $u\approx -1.57861$ and is positive if $u>0$ (see also [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(10(u%5E10%2Bu%5E5-2)-21(u%5E8-u))%2F(u-1))).

So the single staionary point in this case is
$$\{x,\ y\ ,f(x,y)\}=\{1,\ 1,\ 0\}.\tag5$$

$\mathbf{\text{Case }x=\dfrac1{y^2}}$

This case leads to the solution $(5),$ because the task is symmetric on the variables $x,y.$

$\mathbf{\text{Case }y=x}$

The second equation of $(2)$ factor $x^{11}$ leads to the equation $(4),$
with the same solution $(5).$

$\mathbf{\text{Bounds}}$

Note that
$$\lim\limits_{x\to+0}f(x,y) = \lim\limits_{x\to+infty}f(x,y) = \lim\limits_{y\to+0}f(x,y) = \lim\limits_{y\to+\infty}f(x,y) = +\infty\ge0.$$

Therefore,
$$\boxed{\mathbf{(a^5+b^5+c^5)^2\ge3(a^7+b^7+c^7).}}$$

Comment: @AlexFrancisco Thank you. Another way is used.

Answer (score -1):

We start with two identities that we can call [Lamé-type identites](https://sites.google.com/site/tpiezas/001a):
$$(x+y+z)^5 - (x^5+y^5+z^5) = 5(x+y)(x+z)(y+z)(x^2+y^2+z^2+xy+xz+yz)=P$$
$$(x+y+z)^7 - (x^7+y^7+z^7) = 7(x+y)(x+z)(y+z)((x^2+y^2+z^2+xy+xz+yz)^2+xyz(x+y+z))=Q$$

Furthermore we have :

$$(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)=\frac{(a+b+c)^3-a^3-b^3-c^3}{3}$$

Or

With the identity of Gauss we have :

$$a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc=(a+b+c)(a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-bc-ca)$$

So we deduce this :

$$(x+y+z)^5 - (x^5+y^5+z^5) = 5(\frac{(x+y+z)^3+(x+y+z)(xz+yz+yz-x^2-y^2-z^2)-3}{3})(x^2+y^2+z^2+xy+xz+yz)$$

And

$$(x+y+z)^7 - (x^7+y^7+z^7)=7(\frac{(x+y+z)^3+(x+y+z)(xz+yz+yz-x^2-y^2-z^2)-3}{3})((x^2+y^2+z^2+xy+xz+yz)^2+xyz(x+y+z))$$

your inequality is equivalent to with ($xyz=1$) :

$$(x^5+y^5+z^5)^2\ge 3(x^7+y^7+z^7)$$

Or :

$$(x^5+y^5+z^5-(x+y+z)^5+(x+y+z)^5)^2\ge 3(x^7+y^7+z^7-(x+y+z)^7+(x+y+z)^7)$$

Or :

$$(-P+(x+y+z)^5)^2\geq 3(-Q+(x+y+z)^7)$$

Or :

$$-P\geq (3(-Q+(x+y+z)^7))^{0.5}-(x+y+z)^5$$

But :

$$-P=-(x+y+z)^5 + (x^5+y^5+z^5) = 5(\frac{-(x+y+z)^3+(x+y+z)(-xz-yz-yz+x^2+y^2+z^2)+3}{3})((x+y+z)^2-(xy+xz+yz))$$

$$-Q=-(x+y+z)^7 + (x^7+y^7+z^7)=7(\frac{(x+y+z)^3+(x+y+z)(xz+yz+yz-x^2-y^2-z^2)-3}{3})(-(-(x+y+z)^2+xy+zx+yz)^2-xyz(x+y+z))$$

Now we remark that if we put $x+y+z=\alpha$$\quad$ so $xy+yz+zx$ is maximal for $x=y=z=\frac{\alpha}{3}$

Furthermore in $-Q$ all the $xy+yz+zx$ are positive and in $-P$ there are negative so we can minimizing and maximazing the LHS and the RHS respectively

So we can reduce the problem to a one variable problem wich is easily solvable if we remark that :

$$xyz=1 \implies x+y+z\geq 3$$

Comment: Why we need that $xy+xz+yz$ should be maximal? Explain please this point?

Comment: I think it's nothing. Can someone, which up voted this "solution",  explain your step?