# Inequality from AMM problems section

Tags: inequality, recreational-mathematics, substitution, muirhead-inequality, buffalo-way

This is Problem 12024 of AMM.

It asks to show that if $x,y,z$ are positive reals, and $xyz=1$, then $(x^{10}+y^{10}+z^{10})^{2}\geq 3(x^{13}+y^{13}+z^{13})$.

I could show it for the particular case of $z=1$, when it becomes a one variable polynomial inequality.

For the general problem, I thought about homogenizing, by multiplying the right side by $(xyz)^{\frac{7}{3}}$, but couldn't make progress.

Comment: I would Substitute $$x=\frac{a}{b},y=\frac{b}{c},z=\frac{c}{a}$$

Comment: I appreciate that you waited until after the submission period to ask this question. (I can also appreciate wanting to know a solution before the solution is published in $x$ many more months --- I remember anxiously waiting to see how some contest problems were done, back in the day).

Comment: yes, it seems $x\geq 20$ months these days.

Comment: This is very similar to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2732128/prove-this-inequality-by-abc-1, maybe it could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We'll prove that
$$\left(a^{10}+b^{10}+c^{10}\right)^2\geq3(a^{14}+b^{14}+c^{14}),$$ where $abc=1,$  for which it's enough to prove that
$$(x^5+y^5+z^5)^2\geq3xyz(x^7+y^7+z^7)$$ for positives $x$, $y$ and $z$.

Indeed, let $x=\min\{x,y,z\}$, $y=x+u$ and $z=x+v$.

Hence, $$\left(x^5 + y^5 + z^5\right)^2-3xyz\left(x^7 +y^7 + z^7\right)=$$
$$=(u^2-uv+v^2)x^8+8(-u^3+2u^2v+2uv^2-v^3)x^7+$$
$$+4(5u^4-17u^3v+50u^2v^2-17uv^3+5v^4)x^6+$$
$$+8(11u^5-20u^4v+25u^2v^2+25u^2v^3-20uv^4+11v^5)x^5+$$
$$+2(63u^6-79u^5v+50u^4v^2+100u^3v^3+50u^2v^4-79uv^5+63u^6)x^4+$$
$$+4(24u^7-21u^6v+5u^5v^2+25u^4v^3+25u^3v^4+5u^2v^5-21uv^6+24v^7)x^3+$$
$$+2(21u^8-12u^7v+10u^5v^3+25u^4v^4+10u^3v^5-12uv^7+21v^8)x^2+$$
$$+(10u^9-3u^8v+10u^5v^4+10u^4v^5-3uv^8+10v^9)x+(u^5+v^5)^2\geq$$
$$\geq\left((u^2-uv+v^2)x^2-8(u+v)(u^2-3uv+v^2)x+4(5u^4-17u^3v+50u^2v^2-17uv^3+5v^4)\right)x^6.$$

Let $u^2+v^2=tuv$.

Hence, $t\geq2$ and it remains to prove that $$(t-1)(5t^2-17t+40)-4(t+2)(t-3)^2\geq0,$$ which is true because
$$(t-1)(5t^2-17t+40)-4(t+2)(t-3)^2=$$
$$=t^3-6t^2+69t-112=t(t-3)^2+60t-112\geq0.$$
Id est, it's enough to prove that
$$x^{14}+y^{14}+z^{14}\geq x^{13}+y^{13}+z^{13},$$ where $x$, $y$ and $z$ are positives such that $xyz=1$, or
$$x^{42}+y^{42}+z^{42}\geq (x^{39}+y^{39}+z^{39})xyz,$$ which is true by Muirhed because
$$(42,0,0)\succ(40,1,1).$$