# Question about a limit

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I have this problem that I can't solve :

$$\lim_{x\to 1} \frac{\dfrac{1}{(8(x^{1/2^n}+h^4))^{0.25}}+\dfrac{x^{1/2^n}}{h+1} + \dfrac{h}{x^{1/2^n}+1}- \left(\dfrac{1}{(8(x^{1/2^{n+1}}+h^4))^{0.25}} + \dfrac{x^{1/2^{n+1}}}{h+1}+\dfrac{h}{x^{1/2^{n+1}}+1} \right)}{x^{1/2^n}-x^{1/2^{n+1}}}$$

If we treat element by element it's easy but I would like to have another solution.

You can use the L'hospithal rule.

Comment: The ratio is $$\frac{f(x^{1/2^n})-f(x^{1/2^{n+1}})}{x^{1/2^n}-x^{1/2^{n+1}}}$$ for some $C^1$ function $f$ in a neighborhood of $1$ hence the limit is $$f'(1)$$ Now, $$f(x)=(8(x+h^4))^{1/4}+x/(h+1)+h/(x+1)$$ so, where is the problem?

Comment: If you do it term by term, the denominator approaches $0,$ which means you cannot find the limit just by finding the limits of terms separately.

Comment: @MichaelHardy This might not be the "term by term" approach the OP has in mind. There are others, more relevant.

Comment: At the same time, it seems difficult to reconcile "I have this problem that I can't solve" with "If we treat element by element it's easy". OP: Explanations, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given
$$
g(x,n) = {{\Delta _n \,f(x,n)} \over {\Delta _n \,x^{\,1/2^{\,n} } }} \quad \quad
f(x,n) = {1 \over {\left( {8\left( {x^{\,1/2^{\,n} }  + h^{\,4} } \right)} \right)^{\,1/4} }} + {{x^{\,1/2^{\,n} } } \over {h + 1}} + {h \over {x^{\,1/2^{\,n} }  + 1}}
$$
you are, possibly, looking for something like this
$$
\eqalign{
  & \mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to 1} g(x,n)
     = {{\Delta _n \,\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to 1} f(x,n)} \over {\Delta _n \,\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to 1} x^{\,1/2^{\,n} } }} 
     = {{\Delta _n \,\mathop {\lim }\limits_{dx \to 0} f(1 + dx,n)} \over {\Delta _n \,\mathop {\lim }\limits_{dx \to 0} \left( {1 + dx} \right)^{\,1/2^{\,n} } }} =   \cr
  &  = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{dx \to 0} {{\Delta _n \,\left( {f(1,n) + f'(1,n)dx} \right)} \over {\Delta _n \,\left( {1 + {1 \over {2^n }}dx} \right)}}
      = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{dx \to 0} {{\,\Delta _n f(1,n) + \Delta _n f'(1,n)dx} \over { - {1 \over {2^{n + 1} }}dx}} =   \cr 
  &  =  - 2^{n + 1} \Delta _n f'(1,n) \cr} 
$$
since
$$
\Delta _n f(1,n) = 0
$$

It turns out that 
$$
\eqalign{
  & \mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to 1} g(x,n) =  - 2^{n + 1} \Delta _n f'(1,n) =   \cr 
  &  = {1 \over {h + 1}} - {1 \over {2^{\,11/4} \left( {h^{\,4}  + 1} \right)^{\,5/4} }} - {h \over 4} \cr} 
$$
and it does not depend on $n$.

Comment: what happend's if $n$ tends to infiny ?

Comment: @max8128: actually, the limit does not depend on $n$. I added about it to my answer.