# Prove boundedness from below and convexity

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, trigonometry, convex-analysis

For any $a>0$, define
$$f(x):=\cosh(a\sin x)-\cos(a\cos x).$$

1. It appears from plots to be true that $f(x)\ge 1-\cos a$ and $f(x)$ is convex over $\big[0,\frac\pi4\big]$. How would one prove this?
2. Better yet, is there a lower bound simple function, such as an exponential function, which is also bounded from below by some positive number such as $1-\cos a$ and is convex on $\big[0,\frac\pi4\big]$?

---

We can of course examine the second derivative of $f$ which is
\begin{align}&\frac{d^2 f(x)}{dx^2} \\
=& (a\cos x)^2\cosh(a\cos x)-a\sin x\sinh(a\sin x)+(a\sin x)^2\cos(a\cos x) \\
&-a\cos x\sin(a\cos x)
\end{align}
But how do we show the above is positive for $x\in \big[0,\frac\pi4\big]$?

Comment: Are you sure it's convex at $x=\pi/2$?

Comment: @p.s.: I do not know why I wrote $\frac\pi2$... Thank you for catching it. I have corrected it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Partial answer for convexity**.

Let us prove that $f(x)$ is convex if $a \ge 3$.

We have
\begin{align*}
 f''(x) &= (a\cos x)^2\cosh(a\sin x)-a\sin x\, \sinh(a\sin x)+(a\sin x)^2\cos(a\cos x) \\
 &\qquad -a\cos x\,\sin(a\cos x)\\
 &\ge (a\cos x)^2\cosh(a\sin x)-a\sin x\, \cosh(a\sin x) - (a\sin x)^2 - a\\
 &= (a^2 \cos^2 x - a\sin x)\cosh(a\sin x) - a^2\sin^2 x - a\\
 &\ge (a^2 \cos^2 x - a\sin x)\cdot \left(1 + \frac12a^2 \sin^2 x\right) - a^2\sin^2 x - a\\
 &> 0 \tag{1}
\end{align*}
where we use $\cosh u \ge \sinh u$
for all $u \ge 0$, and
$a^2 \cos^2 x - a\sin x \ge 0$,
and $\cosh u \ge 1 + \frac12 u^2$
for all $u \ge 0$.

*Proof of (1)*:

Letting $u = \sin x \in [0, \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}]$, we have
\begin{align*}
 &(a^2 \cos^2 x - a\sin x)\cdot \left(1 + \frac12a^2 \sin^2 x\right) - a^2\sin^2 x - a\\
 ={}& (u^2 - u^4)a^4/2 - u^3 a^3/2 + (1 - 2u^2)a^2 - (1 + u)a\\
 \ge{}& (u^2 - u^4)a^3\cdot 3/2 - u^3 a^3/2 + (1 - 2u^2)a^2 - (1 + u)a\\
 ={}& (-3u^4 - u^3 + 3u^2)a^3/2 + (1 - 2u^2)a^2 - (1 + u)a\\
 \ge{}& (-3u^4 - u^3 + 3u^2)a^2\cdot 3/2 + (1 - 2u^2)a^2 - (1 + u)a\\
 ={}& (-9u^4 - 3u^3 + 5u^2 + 2)a^2/2 - (1 + u)a\\
 \ge{}& (-9u^4 - 3u^3 + 5u^2 + 2)a\cdot 3/2 - (1 + u)a\\
 ={}& (-27u^4 - 9u^3 + 15u^2 - 2u + 4)a/2\\
 \ge{}& \left(-27u^2\cdot \frac12 - 9u\cdot \frac12 + 15u^2 - 2u + 4\right)a/2\\
 ={}& (3u^2 - 13u + 8)a/4\\
 ={}& \frac{(13 - 6u)^2 - 73}{48}\cdot a\\
 \ge{}& \frac{(13 - 6/\sqrt 2)^2 - 73}{48}\cdot a\\
 >{}& 0.
\end{align*}

We are done.

Comment: 1) Will you give a bit detail for the last step? 2) Is there a direct way to prove $f(x)\ge 1-\cos a$?

Comment: @Hans Do you mean $-27u^4 - 9u^3 + 15u^2 - 2u + 4 > 0$?

Comment: Yes. I suppose you can divide the interval up into to 2 parts where $f$ is convex and concave on them respectively. But maybe you have a more elegant way to deal with it.

Comment: @Hans I edited it.

Comment: +1. Very impressive with the successive inequality reducing the order of $a$ in your proof of $(1)$. What prompted you to use this approach?

Comment: @Hans It is a simple trick.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147766/discussion-between-hans-and-river-li).

Comment: @Hans It is fine to comment here.

Comment: The website prompts people to enter into a chat room when the conversation gets long. I was asking if you would list other examples on math.stackexchange of employing this successive bounding trick if you see any.

Comment: @Hans It is simple. I used many times. For example, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1775498/x-y-z-geqslant-0-xy2z3-1-prove-x2yy2zz2x-frac12), we need to prove that $16\,{z}^{9}-56\,{z}^{6}+64\,{z}^{5}+65\,{z}^{3}-64\,{z}^{2}+7 > 0$. First we deal with the term $16z^9$, we can use $\frac{1}{16}(16z^4 - 1)^2z \ge 0$ to get $16z^9 \ge 2z^5 - \frac{1}{16}z$. Then it suffices to prove that $2z^5 - \frac{1}{16}z -56\,{z}^{6}+64\,{z}^{5}+65\,{z}^{3}-64\,{z}^{2}+7 > 0$. Why $\frac{1}{16}(16z^4 - 1)^2z$? Because the minimizer is near $z = 1/2$ (so $16z^4 \approx 1$).

Comment: Are you still working on the case $a<3$?

Comment: @Hans No. However, since $a < 3$,  I think we may use some bounds.

Answer (score 1):

Let us prove that $f(x) \ge 1 - \cos a$ for all $a > 0$ and $x\in [0, \pi/4]$.

Let
$g(a) := \cosh(a\sin x)-\cos(a\cos x) - (1 - \cos a)$.

We have
\begin{align*}
 g'(a) &= \sinh(a\sin x)\, \sin x + \sin(a\cos x)\, \cos x - \sin a\\
 &\ge a\sin x \cdot \sin x + \sin(a\cos x)\, \cos x - \sin a \tag{1} 
\end{align*}
where we use $\sinh u \ge u$ for all $u \ge 0$.

Let $h(x) := a\sin^2 x + \sin(a\cos x)\, \cos x - \sin a$.
We have
\begin{align*}
 h'(x) &= 2a\sin x\, \cos x
 - \cos (a\cos x)\, a \sin x \, \cos x - \sin(a\cos x)\, \sin x\\
 &\ge 2a\sin x \, \cos x
 - a\sin x \, \cos x - \sin(a\cos x)\sin x\\
 &= a\sin x \, \cos x - \sin(a\cos x)\sin x\\
 &= \sin x \, [a\cos x - \sin (a\cos x)]\\
 &\ge 0 \tag{2}
\end{align*}
where we use $u \ge \sin u$ for all $u \ge 0$.

From (2), using $h(0) = 0$, we have $h(x) \ge 0$ for all $x \in [0, \pi/4]$. Thus, $g'(a) \ge 0$ for all $a \ge 0$.
Also, $g(0) = 0$. Thus, $g(a) \ge 0$ for all $a \ge 0$.

We are done.

Comment: +1. Very nice proof.